# INNER JOIN ON vs WHERE clause

Tags: sql, mysql, join, inner-join

For simplicity, assume all relevant fields are `NOT NULL`.

You can do:

```
SELECT
    table1.this, table2.that, table2.somethingelse
FROM
    table1, table2
WHERE
    table1.foreignkey = table2.primarykey
    AND (some other conditions)
```

Or else:

```
SELECT
    table1.this, table2.that, table2.somethingelse
FROM
    table1 INNER JOIN table2
    ON table1.foreignkey = table2.primarykey
WHERE
    (some other conditions)
```

Do these two work on the same way in `MySQL`?

Comment: @Marco: [here it is](http://www.se-radio.net/2009/06/episode-137-sql-with-jim-melton/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL left join vs multiple tables on FROM line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894490/sql-left-join-vs-multiple-tables-on-from-line)

Comment: If I have understood correctly, the first variant is ANSI SQL-89 implicit syntax and the second variant is ANSI SQL-92 explicit join syntax. Both will result in the same result in conforming SQL implementations and both will result in the same query plan in well done SQL implementations. I personally prefer SQL-89 syntax but many people prefer SQL-92 syntax.

Comment: @Hogan I was pointing out the official names for different syntaxes. None of the answers explicitly spelled out the full names so I decided to add those as comments. However, my comment did not answer the actual question so I added that as as comment, not as an answer. (High voted answers have claims such as "INNER JOIN is ANSI syntax" and "implicit join ANSI syntax is older" which says nothing at all because both syntaxes are different ANSI syntaxes.)

Answer (score 796, accepted):

`INNER JOIN` is ANSI syntax that you should use.

It is generally considered more readable, especially when you join lots of tables.

It can also be easily replaced with an `OUTER JOIN` whenever a need arises.

The `WHERE` syntax is more relational model oriented.

A result of two tables `JOIN`ed is a cartesian product of the tables to which a filter is applied which selects only those rows with joining columns matching.

It's easier to see this with the `WHERE` syntax.

As for your example, in MySQL (and in SQL generally) these two queries are synonyms.

Also, note that MySQL also has a `STRAIGHT_JOIN` clause.

Using this clause, you can control the `JOIN` order: which table is scanned in the outer loop and which one is in the inner loop.

You cannot control this in MySQL using `WHERE` syntax.

Comment: Thanks, Quassnoi. You've got alot of details in your ans; is it fair to say that "yes, those queries are equivalent, but you should use inner join because it's more readable, and easier to modify"?

Comment: @allyourcode: for `Oracle`, `SQL Server`, `MySQL` and `PostgreSQL` — yes. For other systems, probably, too, but you better check.

Comment: FWIW, using commas with join conditions in the `WHERE` clause is also in the ANSI standard.

Comment: `@Bill Karwin`: `JOIN` keyword was not a part of proprietary standards until the past more recent that it may seem. It made its way into `Oracle` only in version `9` and into `PostgreSQL` in version `7.2` (both released in `2001`). Appearance of this keyword was a part of `ANSI` standard adoption, and that's why this keyword is usually associated with `ANSI`, despite the fact the latter supports comma as a synonym for `CROSS JOIN` as well.

Comment: Nevertheless, ANSI SQL-89 specified joins to be done with commas and conditions in a `WHERE` clause (without conditions, a join is equivalent to a cross join, as you said).  ANSI SQL-92 added the `JOIN` keyword and related syntax, but comma-style syntax is still supported for backward compatiblity.

Comment: InterBase 4.0 is an example of a commercial RDBMS implementation that supported `JOIN` syntax as early as 1994.

Comment: Just a note to be clear, implicit vs explicit joins are NOT the same, implicit joins will surprise you every once in a while when "nothing changed", especifically when dealing with null values (bugs in production); if you want to joins tables, do so explicitly (join... on...) and avoid your self the headache

Comment: @BlackTigerX: could you please be more specific about implicit and explicit joins "being not the same"?

Comment: Again, it's when working with null values, usually with joins on multiple columns, and some of those values are null, you will get different results (e.g.: empty vs not empty) depending on which join you use

Comment: is there a performance gain by using `join on` instead of using `WHERE`?

Comment: Implicit join (,) is exactly the same as CROSS JOIN and (INNER) JOIN ON 1=1 except it has lower precedence. (OUTER) LEFT/RIGHT/FULL JOINs differ from (INNER) JOIN (they can add extra rows with NULLs). You do have to use ON in JOINs before OUTER JOINs if you don't use a subselect with WHERE instead. (@BlackTigerX is wrong.)

Answer (score 232):

Others have pointed out that `INNER JOIN` helps human readability, and that's a top priority, I agree.
Let me try to explain *why* the join syntax is more readable.

A basic `SELECT` query is this:

```
SELECT stuff
FROM tables
WHERE conditions
```

The `SELECT` clause tells us **what** we're getting back; the `FROM` clause tells us **where** we're getting it from, and the `WHERE` clause tells us **which** ones we're getting.

`JOIN` is a statement about the tables, how they are bound together (conceptually, actually, into a single table).

Any query elements that control the tables - where we're getting stuff from - semantically belong to the `FROM` clause (and of course, that's where `JOIN` elements go).  Putting joining-elements into the `WHERE` clause conflates the **which** and the **where-from**, that's why the `JOIN` syntax is preferred.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying why inner join is preferred Carl. I think your ans was implicit in the others, but explicit is usually better (yes, I'm a Python fan).

Comment: The semantics of ON and WHERE mean that for JOINs after the last OUTER JOIN *it doesn't matter* which you use. Although you characterize ON as part of the JOIN, it is *also* a filtering after a Cartesian product. *Both* ON and WHERE filter a Cartesian product. But either ON  or a subselect with WHERE must be used *before* the last OUTER JOIN. (JOINs aren't "on" column pairs. Any two tables can be JOINed ON any condition. That's just a way to interpret JOINs ON equality of columns specifically.)

Comment: Even when you are using WHERE to the same effect of INNER JOIN, you are going to mention your two tables in the FROM part of the query. So basically you are still implying where you are getting your data in the FROM clause, so I guess you cannot say it necessarily "conflates the which and the where-from"

Comment: @ArsenKhachaturyan Just because a keyword or identifier is used in text doesn't mean it is code & needs code format. That is a formatting choice that could go any way & if it is reasonable to edit here then it is justifiable for every post to be constantly edited to the other format--which is to say, it's not justifiable. (Plus inline per-word code format can be difficult to read.) Same for the paragraph breaks here--they aren't particularly clarify. Same with 'which' vs 'that'. And names of programming languages should *not* be in code format. PS You added a line break in error.

Comment: @philipxy as you mentioned "it doesn't mean...", but obviously neither that meant that it can't be marked with code keyword. Yes it's choice to be made but a lot of posts are done without knowing that fact. Hence my decision to make the changes are not intended to break anything but make it more readable. If you noticed any break after formating changes, sorry for that, and you obviously can revert such changes.

Comment: @ArsenKhachaturyan It means it should *not* be changed, as I explained, because otherwise endless pointless edits would be justified, and you are making endless pointless edits, merely changing to one style over another, and not the author's chosen style at that.

Comment: @philipxy I think we are not getting to each other, your observations around that there is no meaning of edit is a matter of choice topic and I don't think we should have an endless discussion around it. Like I said before whatever initially is chosen by the author doesn't necessarily mean it is the best version and if the author disagrees with the change StackOverflow always allows to revert it. So please lets' stop here and don't go further with this discussion.

Answer (score 166):

**Applying conditional statements in ON / WHERE**

Here I have explained the logical query processing steps.

---

Reference: Inside Microsoft® SQL Server™ 2005 T-SQL Querying 
Publisher: Microsoft Press 
Pub Date: March 07, 2006 
Print ISBN-10: 0-7356-2313-9 
Print ISBN-13: 978-0-7356-2313-2 
Pages: 640

[Inside Microsoft® SQL Server™ 2005 T-SQL Querying](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/book.aspx?ID=9615&locale=en-us)

```
(8)  SELECT (9) DISTINCT (11) TOP <top_specification> <select_list>
(1)  FROM <left_table>
(3)       <join_type> JOIN <right_table>
(2)       ON <join_condition>
(4)  WHERE <where_condition>
(5)  GROUP BY <group_by_list>
(6)  WITH {CUBE | ROLLUP}
(7)  HAVING <having_condition>
(10) ORDER BY <order_by_list>
```

The first noticeable aspect of SQL that is different than other programming languages is the order in which the code is processed. In most programming languages, the code is processed in the order in which it is written. In SQL, the first clause that is processed is the FROM clause, while the SELECT clause, which appears first, is processed almost last.

Each step generates a virtual table that is used as the input to the following step. These virtual tables are not available to the caller (client application or outer query). Only the table generated by the final step is returned to the caller. If a certain clause is not specified in a query, the corresponding step is simply skipped.

## Brief Description of Logical Query Processing Phases

Don't worry too much if the description of the steps doesn't seem to make much sense for now. These are provided as a reference. Sections that come after the scenario example will cover the steps in much more detail.

1. FROM: A Cartesian product (cross join) is performed between the first two tables in the FROM clause, and as a result, virtual table VT1 is generated.
2. ON: The ON filter is applied to VT1. Only rows for which the `<join_condition>` is TRUE are inserted to VT2.
3. OUTER (join): If an OUTER JOIN is specified (as opposed to a CROSS JOIN or an INNER JOIN), rows from the preserved table or tables for which a match was not found are added to the rows from VT2 as outer rows, generating VT3. If more than two tables appear in the FROM clause, steps 1 through 3 are applied repeatedly between the result of the last join and the next table in the FROM clause until all tables are processed.
4. WHERE: The WHERE filter is applied to VT3. Only rows for which the `<where_condition>` is TRUE are inserted to VT4.
5. GROUP BY: The rows from VT4 are arranged in groups based on the column list specified in the GROUP BY clause. VT5 is generated.
6. CUBE | ROLLUP: Supergroups (groups of groups) are added to the rows from VT5, generating VT6.
7. HAVING: The HAVING filter is applied to VT6. Only groups for which the `<having_condition>` is TRUE are inserted to VT7.
8. SELECT: The SELECT list is processed, generating VT8.
9. DISTINCT: Duplicate rows are removed from VT8. VT9 is generated.
10. ORDER BY: The rows from VT9 are sorted according to the column list specified in the ORDER BY clause. A cursor is generated (VC10).
11. TOP: The specified number or percentage of rows is selected from the beginning of VC10. Table VT11 is generated and returned to the caller.

---

Therefore, (INNER JOIN) ON will filter the data (the data count of VT will be reduced here itself) before applying the WHERE clause.  The subsequent join conditions will be executed with filtered data which improves performance. After that, only the WHERE condition will apply filter conditions.

(Applying conditional statements in ON / WHERE will not make much difference in few cases. This depends on how many tables you have joined and the number of rows available in each join tables)

Comment: *"Therefore, (INNER JOIN) ON will filter the data (The data count of VT will be reduced here itself) before applying WHERE clause."* Not necessarily. The article is about the *logical* order of processing. When you say a particular implementation will do one thing before another thing, you're talking about the *implemented* order of processing. Implementations are allowed to make any optimizations they like, as long as the result is the same as if the implementation followed the logical order. Joe Celko has written a lot about this on Usenet.

Answer (score 77):

The implicit join ANSI syntax is older, less obvious, and not recommended.

In addition, the relational algebra allows interchangeability of the predicates in the `WHERE` clause and the `INNER JOIN`, so even `INNER JOIN` queries with `WHERE` clauses can have the predicates rearranged by the optimizer.

I recommend you write the queries in the most readable way possible.

Sometimes this includes making the `INNER JOIN` relatively "incomplete" and putting some of the criteria in the `WHERE` simply to make the lists of filtering criteria more easily maintainable.

For example, instead of:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN CustomerAccounts ca
    ON ca.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    AND c.State = 'NY'
INNER JOIN Accounts a
    ON ca.AccountID = a.AccountID
    AND a.Status = 1
```

Write:

```
SELECT *
FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN CustomerAccounts ca
    ON ca.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
INNER JOIN Accounts a
    ON ca.AccountID = a.AccountID
WHERE c.State = 'NY'
    AND a.Status = 1
```

But it depends, of course.

Comment: Your first snippet definitely hurts my brain more. Does anyone actually do that? If I meet someone that does that, is it ok for me to beat him over the head?

Comment: I locate the criteria where it makes the most sense.  If I'm joining to a temporally consistent snapshot lookup table (and I don't have a view or UDF which enforces the selection of a valid date), I will include the effective date in the join and not in the WHERE because it's less likely to accidentally get removed.

Comment: @allyourcode: though it's rare to see this type of join syntax in INNER JOINs, it's quite common for RIGHT JOINs and LEFT JOINS -- specifying more detail in the join predicate eliminates the need for a subquery and prevents your outer joins from inadvertently being turned into INNER JOINs.  (Though I agree that for INNER JOINs I'd almost always put c.State = 'NY' in the WHERE clause)

Comment: @allyourcode I definitely do that! And I agree with Cade.. I'm curious as to whether there is a [decent reason not to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25272658/position-of-inner-join-filtering-conditions-in-a-query-on-or-where-clause)

Answer (score 39):

Implicit joins (which is what your first query is known as) become much much more confusing, hard to read, and hard to maintain once you need to start adding more tables to your query. Imagine doing that same query and type of join on four or five different tables ... it's a nightmare.

Using an explicit join (your second example) is much more readable and easy to maintain.

Comment: I couldn't disagree more.  JOIN syntax is extremely wordy and difficult to organize.  I have plenty of queries joining 5, 10, even 15 tables using WHERE clause joins and they are perfectly readable.  Rewriting such a query using a JOIN syntax results in a garbled mess.

Which just goes to show there is no right answer to this question and that it depends more on what you're comfortable with.

Comment: Noah, I think you might be in the minority here.

Comment: I get +1 to matt and Noah. I like diversity :). I can see where Noah is coming from; inner join doesn't add anything new to the language, and is definitely more verbose. On the other hand, it can make your 'where' condition much shorter, which usually means it's easier to read.

Comment: I would assume that any sane DBMS would translate the two queries into the same execution plan; however in reality each DBMS is different and the only way to know for sure is to actually examine the execution plan (i.e., you'll have to test it yourself).

Answer (score 33):

I'll also point out that using the older syntax is more subject to error. If you use inner joins without an ON clause, you will get a syntax error. If you use the older syntax and forget one of the join conditions in the where clause, you will get a cross join. The developers often fix this by adding the distinct keyword (rather than fixing the join because they still don't realize the join itself is broken) which may appear to cure the problem but will slow down the query considerably.

Additionally for maintenance if you have a cross join in the old syntax, how will the maintainer know if you meant to have one (there are situations where cross joins are needed) or if it was an accident that should be fixed?

Let me point you to this question to see why the implicit syntax is bad if you use left joins.
[Sybase *= to Ansi Standard with 2 different outer tables for same inner table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186549/sybase-to-ansi-standard-with-2-different-outer-tables-for-same-inner-table#comment16335545_12186549)

Plus (personal rant here), the standard using the explicit joins is over 20 years old, which means implicit join syntax has been outdated for those 20 years. Would you write application code using a syntax that has been outdated for 20 years? Why do you want to write database code that is?

Comment: @HLGEM: While I agree completely that explicit JOINs are better, there are cases when you just need to use the old syntax. A real world example: ANSI JOIN's got into Oracle only in version 9i which was released in 2001, and until only a year ago (16 years from the moment the standard was published) I had to support a bunch of 8i installation for which we had to release critical updates. I didn't want to maintain two sets of updates, so we developed and tested the updates against all databases including 8i, which meant we were unable to use ANSI JOINs.

Comment: +1 interesting point when you point out that the sintax without INNER JOIN is more error prone. I'm confused about your last sentence when you say "...the standard using the explicit joins is 17 years old." so are you then suggesting to use the INNER JOIN keyword or not?

Comment: @Marco Demaio, yes always use INNER JOIN or JOIN  (these two are the same)or  LEFT JOIN or RIGHT JOIN or CROSS JOIN and never use the implicit comma joins.

Comment: "Why do you want to write database code that is [20 years old]?" - I notice **you** write SQL using `HAVING` which has been 'outdated' since SQL started supporting derived tables. I also notice you don't use `NATURAL JOIN` even though I would argue it has made `INNER JOIN` 'outdated'. Yes, you have your reasons (no need to state them again here!): my point is, those who like using the older syntax have their reasons too and the relative age of the syntax is of little if any relevance.

Comment: Natural Joins are not supported in the database I use. I don't understand why HAVING is replaced by derived tables, please explain, I really would be interested. However, I have never seen anyone who uses implicit joins give a reason to use them that isn't,"It is what I am used to."  If you have one, I would like to hear it. There is no technical advantage that I know of for an implicit join over an inner join. There are technical disadvantages because implicit joins can lead to bad result sets due to unidentified accidental cross joins which are not possible using the inner join syntax.

Comment: @onedaywhen, It is especially critical that people new to SQL avoid implicit joins, they are the very people who get wrong results because they don't understand join concepts. And you are still writing the join conditions in the where clause so you save nothing except the time it takes to write the word join. Given that you write the conditions later in the query, it probably actually takes less time thanjumping up and down in the query to add the where clause as you add the join.  The I'm too tired argument is silly. You can write joins as easily or more easily than an implicit join.

Comment: Wasn't looking for an argument, genuinely though you wanted info from me. But I maintain that "outdated for 20 years" is a poor defense and stand by my original comments.

Answer (score 16):

The SQL:2003 standard changed some precedence rules so a JOIN statement takes precedence over a "comma" join. This can actually change the results of your query depending on how it is setup. This cause some problems for some people when MySQL 5.0.12 switched to adhering to the standard.

So in your example, your queries would work the same. But if you added a third table:
SELECT ... FROM table1, table2 JOIN table3 ON ... WHERE ...

Prior to MySQL 5.0.12, table1 and table2 would be joined first, then table3. Now (5.0.12 and on), table2 and table3 are joined first, then table1. It doesn't always change the results, but it can and you may not even realize it.

I never use the "comma" syntax anymore, opting for your second example. It's a lot more readable anyway, the JOIN conditions are with the JOINs, not separated into a separate query section.

Comment: Standard SQL didn't change. MySQL was just wrong & now is right. See the MySQL manual.

Answer (score 15):

They have a different human-readable meaning.

However, depending on the query optimizer, they may have the same meaning to the machine.

You should always code to be readable.

That is to say, if this is a built-in relationship, use the explicit join.  if you are matching on weakly related data, use the where clause.

Answer (score 7):

I know you're talking about MySQL, but anyway:
In Oracle 9 explicit joins and implicit joins would generate different execution plans. AFAIK that has been solved in Oracle 10+: there's no such difference anymore.

Answer (score 4):

ANSI join syntax is definitely more portable.

I'm going through an upgrade of Microsoft SQL Server, and I would also mention that the =* and *= syntax for outer joins in SQL Server is not supported (without compatibility mode) for 2005 SQL server and later.

Comment: Even in SQL Server 2000, *= and =* could give wrong results and should never be used.

Comment: `*=` and `=*` were never ANSI and were never a good notation. That's why ON was needed--for OUTER JOINs in the absence of subselects (which got added at the same time, so they aren't actually needed in CROSS & INNER JOINs.)

Answer (score 3):

If you are often programming dynamic stored procedures, you will fall in love with your second example (using where). If you have various input parameters and lots of morph mess, then that is the only way. Otherwise, they both will run the same query plan so there is definitely no obvious difference in classic queries.

Answer (score 1):

I have two points for the implicit join (The second example):

1. Tell the database what you want, not what it should do.
2. You can write all tables in a clear list that is not cluttered by join conditions. Then you can much easier read what tables are all mentioned. The conditions come all in the WHERE part, where they are also all lined up one below the other. Using the JOIN keyword mixes up tables and conditions.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Also implicit join is comma, as in the 1st code block, and what you are suggesting. And the code you suggest is already in the question. Also neither code block is any more or less declarative or procedural than the other.