# SQL 2000 to SQL 2008

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

I have a query in SQL 2000 DB and I need to migrate it to SQL 2008 DB. It works fine in SQL2000 and I j’t need to revamp it into SQL2008. Below is the query in SQL2000. Please guide me how can we overload `*=` , `=*` clause in ON clause.

```
SELECT tblacc. *
FROM   tblacc,
       tblst,
       tblreceipt,
       tblrtemp,
       tblitem
WHERE  tblacc.rkey = tblreceipt.rkey
       AND tblacc.stkey = tblst.stkey
       AND tblacc.stkey *= tblrtemp.stkey
       AND tblacc.stkey *= tblitem.stkey
       AND tblacc.itkey *= tblitem.itkey
       AND tblrtemp.rkey =* tblreceipt.rkey
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT tblacc.*
FROM   tblacc
  INNER JOIN tblreceipt ON tblacc.rkey = tblreceipt.rkey
  INNER JOIN tblst      ON tblacc.stkey = tblst.stkey
  LEFT JOIN  tblitem    ON tblacc.stkey = tblitem.stkey
                       AND tblacc.itkey = tblitem.itkey
  LEFT JOIN  tblrtemp   ON tblacc.stkey = tblrtemp.stkey
                       AND tblrtemp.rkey = tblreceipt.rkey
```

Answer (score 2):

*= is a left Join

=* is a right Join

Have you tried bringing it up in the SQL Editor in SQL Server Management Studio?
It might convert it for you.

Comment: Good suggestion I just tried `select * from master..spt_values v1, master..spt_values v2 WHERE v1.number *=  v2.number` clicked "Design Query in Editor" and it did rewrite it. Apparently there are cases where [the old style syntax is ambiguous](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/brian_kelley/archive/2007/11/01/3087.aspx) so not sure how it handles those.

Comment: It doesn't seem to like the OP's query though.

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear what you mean by "overload `*=`, `=*` clause in ON clause", unfortunately.  I can see one problem, however: you are using the old-style syntax for outer joins.  You should replace this syntax by [the new "ANSI SQL" syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms187518).  This uses keywords rather than `*=` and `=*`, and moves the join condition into the `FROM` clause:

- `WHERE a.x *= b.y` becomes `FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.x = b.y`
- `WHERE a.x =* b.y` becomes `FROM a RIGHT OUTER JOIN b ON a.x = b.y`
- There is also `FROM a FULL OUTER JOIN b ON a.x = b.y`, which pads un-matched tuples from *either* table with NULLs.

The old syntax [has been deprecated since SQL Server 2005](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wardpond/archive/2008/09/13/deprecation-of-old-style-join-syntax-only-a-partial-thing.aspx) because it was non-standard and prone to introducing ambiguity.  It is [not available on databases running in SQL Server 2005 or later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894490/sql-left-join-vs-multiple-tables-on-from-line/894659#894659) compatibility mode, which is likely the source of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the query should be something like below, though I don't know if you want to do an `INNER JOIN` and a `RIGHT JOIN` with the table `tblreceipt`.

```
SELECT tblacc.*
FROM   tblacc
JOIN   tblreceipt
    ON tblacc.rkey = tblreceipt.rkey
JOIN   tblst
    ON tblacc.stkey = tblst.stkey
LEFT JOIN tblrtemp
    ON tblacc.stkey = tblrtemp.stkey
LEFT JOIN tblitem
    ON tblacc.stkey = tblitem.stkey AND tblacc.itkey = tblitem.itkey
RIGHT JOIN tblreceipt
    ON tblrtemp.rkey = tblreceipt.rkey
```