# Joining tables or to select from multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join, oracle10g

Which is better in between *joining a table* or *selecting from multiple tables* ?

For instance, lets assume the following similar scenario:

Using ***join***:

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(SALARY),0) FROM X
JOIN Y ON X.X_ID=Y.Y_X_ID
```

**OR**

By ***selecting from multiple tables***

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(SALARY),0) FROM X, Y
WHERE X.X_ID=Y.Y_X_ID
```

Comment: They are the same thing. See the execution plans. The second is also a join(is Oracle syle join). You should however use the first style which is more explicit and worldwide used.

Comment: Speaking of ANSI and compatibility, try to get out of the habit of using Nvl(). Coalesce() is the standard function, and it's more flexible and some cases performs better than Nvl() due to short-circuit evaluation

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL left join vs multiple tables on FROM line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894490/sql-left-join-vs-multiple-tables-on-from-line)

Answer (score 2):

Both are joins. The first is an explicit join and the second one is an implicit join and is a SQL antipattern.

The second one is bad because it is easy to get an accidental cross join. It is also bad becasue when you want a cross join, it is not clear if your did want that or if you have an accidental one.

Further in the second style if you ned to convert to an outer join, you need to change all joins in the query or risk getting incorrect results. So the second style is harder to maintain.

Explcit joins were institututed in the last century, why anyone is still using error-prone and hard to maintain implicit joins is beyond me.

Answer (score 2):

mainly join is used to retrieve data from multiple tables
so in sql there are 3 types join are available

1. Equi join-inner join
           outer join-left
                      right
                      full
2. Non equi join
3. Self join
4. Cross join

Answer (score 1):

You should use the **JOIN** syntax for a lot of reasons which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1018825/1599054).

Moreover this syntax has the advantage to give some hints to the query optimizer (during the computation of weights, weights computed directly by the facts mentionned in this syntax are more favorably weighted than the others).