# Android : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

Tags: java, android

```
Cursor ck = db.rawQuery("select name,title,text,type from abstracts_item,abstract_author,authors_abstract where abstract_author._id == authors_abstract.abstractauthor_id and abstracts_item._id ==  authors_abstract.abstractsitem_id", null);
```

I was run this same query with other sqlite tool. It works just fine. But, when I try to use with `cursor`. I got an error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
```

I got so many solutions. But, nothing worked for me. I will be happy, if you guys help me to solve that.

Comment: "from abstracts_item,abstract_author,authors_abstract", from clause with 3 tables, is this valid syntax?

Comment: @Nambari  Nope!  I'm  struggling to understand how this works in "other sqlite tool" without the required joins.

Comment: It just working fine in adb shell

Comment: It is valid syntax. It's an implied join.

Comment: @Benito: Thanks! Good to know about this. It seems this technique is not that much popular.

Comment: @Benito.  Thanks for that.  I didn't know that, I assume this is an inner join?  I think I prefer an explicit join since the intent is clear.

Comment: You are correct. It is valid, yet deprecated. Check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/894659/1117415) if you want more details.

Comment: @Benito thanks again, great Q&A you linked - and after reading it, I'm glad that it's being deprecated!  I just +1 one of your answers by way of a proper thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

The SQL language does not use `==` but rather `=`.

so it s/b:

```
Cursor ck = db.rawQuery("select name,title,text,type from
abstracts_item,abstract_author,authors_abstract where abstract_author._id =
authors_abstract.abstractauthor_id and abstracts_item._id =
authors_abstract.abstractsitem_id", null);
```

You could also increase performance by using **inner joins** rather that a where clause:

```
Cursor ck = db.rawQuery("select name,title,text,type from abstracts_item 
    inner join abstract_author on abstract_author._id = authors_abstract.abstractauthor_id
    inner join authors_abstract on abstracts_item._id = authors_abstract.abstractsitem_id", null);
```