# MYSQL query through many layers of one to many relationships

Tags: mysql

How do I select all things from the many of a one to many relationship, several layers down in many one-to-many relationships? I'm not sure how to nest all those left joins.

Example

```
There are many Institutions
Each Institution has many Departments
Each Department has many Forums
Each Forum has many Users
Each User has many Posts
Each Post has many Comments
```

Find all Comments for an Institution.

I googled around, but I'm not sure what the name for this is - chain nested one to many relationship queries? The closest I found was [SQL left join vs multiple tables on FROM line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894490/sql-left-join-vs-multiple-tables-on-from-line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing your schema and making some assumptions:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM
    Institution i
    INNER JOIN Department d ON d.InstitutionID = i.InstitutionID
    INNER JOIN Forums f ON f.DepartmentID = d.DepartmentID
    INNER JOIN `User` u ON u.ForumID = f.ForumID
    INNER JOIN Post p ON p.UserID = u.UserID
    INNER JOIN Comment c ON c.PostID = p.PostID
WHERE
    i.InstitutionID = 42
```