# SQL - Difference between WHERE with two tables and a JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

Here are these two SQL queries:

```
SELECT `o`.`date`, `i`.`description`, `o`.`quantity`
FROM `orders` AS `o`, `items` AS `i`
WHERE `i`.`itemID` = `o`.`itemID`;
```

and

```
SELECT `o`.`date`, `i`.`description`, `o`.`quantity`
FROM `orders` AS `o`
JOIN `items` AS `i`
ON `i`.`itemID` = `o`.`itemID`;
```

I get one result less with the first one.
Can someone explain the difference between the two?

Comment: Possible duplicat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins

Comment: These queries are functionally identical. Could you provide some sample data or a fiddle to reproduce the issue?

Comment: They are functionally equivalent.  I have never experienced a situation where the same results aren't returned.  FYI:  The first style is often referred to as 'theta' style.  The 2nd is the ANSI style

Comment: can you give me some links about theta and ansi?

Comment: Google it.  I learned about the difference in the Pro MySQL book by Jay Pipes and Michael Kruckenberg

Comment: Perhaps you have `LEFT JOIN` in the second query? Otherwise, this shouldn't happen and the two queries should return the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are functionally equivalent because MySQL optimizer rewrites theta join into an ANSI JOIN (atleast MySQL 5.6 does)

You can check this with EXPLAIN EXTENDED your_query ; SHOW WARNINGS;

**theta style join**

```
SELECT `o`.`date`, `i`.`description`, `o`.`quantity`
FROM `orders` AS `o`, `items` AS `i`
WHERE `i`.`itemID` = `o`.`itemID`;
```

**ANSI JOIN**

```
SELECT `o`.`date`, `i`.`description`, `o`.`quantity`
FROM `orders` AS `o`
JOIN `items` AS `i`
ON `i`.`itemID` = `o`.`itemID`;
```

The only real difference is readability the theta style makes it easier to mis that it is an INNER JOIN, so make an habit out off it to write the ANSI JOIN

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [usefull discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894490/sql-left-join-vs-multiple-tables-on-from-line) around what you want to do

[SQL left join vs multiple tables on FROM line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894490/sql-left-join-vs-multiple-tables-on-from-line)

Hope it helps !