# Sum all rows returning from SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, sum

```
SELECT SUM(SELECT type.value
FROM type,item_type 
WHERE item_type.type_id = type.id AND item_type.type_id IN (4,7)
GROUP BY type.id)
```

What's wrong with this query? I would like to sum all rows coming from the internal query.

Comment: Why do you not use SUM without internal query?

Comment: Because the internal query is using GROUP BY, this way SUM is affected by that statement. I want to sum all rows with **distinct id**, *displaying the sum from all distinct ids in one row*.

Comment: @Richard . . . Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 4):

You can't use SUM() function with subquerys. According to the manual the SUM() function returns the total sum of a numeric column. The way you were doing, was something like that: SELECT 1+50+30+10. Where is the table you were selecting the values? The sintax is:

```
SELECT SUM(column) FROM table
```

Take a look at: 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp

The correct way is

```
SELECT t.id, SUM(t.value)
FROM type as t,
INNER JOIN item_type as it
ON it.type_id = t.id
WHERE it.type_id IN (4,7)
GROUP BY t.id
```

Consider to use JOIN sintax instead of multiple tables: [SQL left join vs multiple tables on FROM line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894490/sql-left-join-vs-multiple-tables-on-from-line)

Comment: I edited and tried to explain better. Please try again!

Answer (score 1):

You should learn to use proper `join` syntax and table aliases:

```
SELECT SUM(t.value)
FROM type t JOIN
     item_type it
     ON it.type_id = t.id 
WHERE it.type_id IN (4,7);
```

If you want one row for each `type.id`, then you need a `GROUP BY`.

Your query doesn't work because subqueries are not allowed as arguments to aggregation functions.  Even if they were, the context would be for a scalar subquery and your subquery is likely to return more than one row.

Comment: It should work, but GROUP BY is avoiding repeated values in `id` column. At the same time I would like to display the sum from all distinct ids in one row.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `SUM` without internal query :

```
SELECT type.id, SUM(type.value)
FROM type,item_type 
WHERE item_type.type_id = type.id AND item_type.type_id IN (4,7)
GROUP BY type.id
```

Comment: [...] displaying the sum from all distinct ids in one row. :/

Comment: @Richard This query return one row with value of sum for distinct ids

Comment: `item_type` is the relation between `type` table and `item` table. This relation is **n to n**, 'cause of this value can be duplicated.

Comment: @Richard Please see your query, you select all values with distinct id and then try to get SUM of these values. The same work do the query above. Could you please more explain you problem?