# Finding teacher that only taught one class

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to ask what would I add to my query to select the ones that only taught one class. My table is:

```
Teacher                         Course
ID    Name                      Course_ID   Teacher_ID
1     George                    1           1
2     Sam                       2           2
3     Julie                     3           1
```

I want to get the teacher ID who only taught one class. I have:

```
select teacher.id
from teacher, course
where teacher.id = course.teacher_id;
```

I was thinking of adding

```
having (count(course.teacher_id)) = 1
```

or

```
where count(t) = (select count(*) from course) and t = 0
```

but I get an "invalid use of group error". How do I change it to fix my query?

Comment: you use 'having' without join to course table? check @forward's answer.

Comment: Did you use `GROUP BY teacher.id` when you tried `having (count(course.teacher_id)) = 1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have tried is almost there, just add `group by`, and use `join` not `,` to combine tables:

```
select teacher.id
from teacher
join course
on teacher.id = course.teacher_id
group by teacher.id
having (count(course.Course_ID)) = 1 -- note count(Course_ID), not count(teacher_id)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works but I want to ask why use `join` and not `,` ? What is the difference between the two?

Comment: @FORWARD As he mention extra where condition,it automatically convert full join to Join so i don't think it make much impact.

Comment: @JMei about difference, please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894490/sql-left-join-vs-multiple-tables-on-from-line).

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code.Hope this will helps.

```
select teacher.id
from teacher, course
where teacher.id = course.teacher_id
GROUP BY course.teacher_id
HAVING COUNT(course. Course_ID) =1
```

Comment: thanks! it works. This is closer to what I had, but what is the difference between this one and the first one?

Comment: @JMei he made `JOIN` and i had used `*,*` with where condition.

Comment: sorry, I meant what's the difference between using `join` and the `,` with `where`

Comment: **,** means full join without any condition,where as `JOIN` is with some condition mention as `ON` clause.

Comment: ahh. Thanks! that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Join with a group by and having:

```
select *
from teacher
where id in (
    select teacher_id
    from course
    group by teacher_id
    having count(*) = 1)
```