# Get CSV from query which involves multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm trying to make a query to extract elements from 2 tables, which are linked via another table.

So I have 3 tables:

```
authors
 - id, name, book
category
 - id, name, description
category-author
 - id, idauthor, idcategory
```

Now I want to make a query to make the following output:

```
row: authors.id, authors.name, authors.book, category.name
```

I don't know what category's are linked using the 2 tables only, so I need to use the last one, the category-author table. The id's of both the author and the category are linked via that table.

I got the following query:

```
SELECT authors.id, authors.name, authors.book, category.name FROM category, author LEFT JOIN SELECT ??
```

I'm stuck at the remaining part of the query.

Also when I have this query, can I just extract a CSV with phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get related information from different tables using table joins. Relations between tables should be specified using foreign keys (i.e. the column `idcategory` from `category-author` is presumably a foreign key that refers to primary key column `category.id`). In a join clause, you merely specify which tables are to be joined and on what column:

`SELECT table1.col1, table2.col2
 FROM table1
 JOIN table2 ON table1.pkCol = table2.fkCol`

This means you can't specify any `SELECT` or `FROM` clauses within a JOIN clause. The columns you wish to select from joined tables are all specified in the initial `SELECT` statement, and you only specify one table in the `FROM` clause, from which you subsequently perform the table joins. 
In your case, I think this should get you started:

```
SELECT authors.id, authors.name, authors.book, category.name 
FROM category 
LEFT JOIN category-author ON category-author.idcategory = category.id
LEFT JOIN authors ON authors.id = category-author.idauthor
```

I'm not sure how familiar you are with foreign keys, primary keys and table joins, so I won't elaborate any more on this. I think specifying multiple tables in a `FROM` clause is bad practice, even if your database system still supports it ([Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894490/sql-left-join-vs-multiple-tables-on-from-line)).

From then on, you can easily export the results from within PhpMyAdmin, as there is an export button for every table overview, including query results.