# Understanding where clause vs join

Tags: sql, join, db2

Can somebody explain the difference between below query examples.

```
select column1,column2 
from table1 
join table2 
  on table1.columna = table2.columna 
  and columna='1234'
```

vs

```
select column1,column2 
from table1 
join table2 
  on table1.columna = table2.columna 
where columna='1234'
```

Comment: Possible Duplicates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894490/sql-left-join-vs-multiple-tables-on-from-line

Comment: it's not duplicated for those questions, it just sounds similar.

Comment: The first query performs filtering while joining, the second does filtering after joining. For inner joins, the result will be equivalent, unlike for outer joins.

Comment: For INNER JOIN there is no difference, the results of both queries are the same. The difference will be for LEFT/RIGHT/FULL OUTER joins, but this is not a subject of this question.

Comment: @vc74 thanks that makes sense.

Comment: @krokodilko thank you

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more about the change as what will happen as how the results will differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question in your comment, with the following tables:

**table1** and **table2**

```
+---------+---------+    +---------+---------+ 
| column1 | columna |    | column2 | columna |
+---------+---------+    +---------+---------+
|      10 |    1234 |    |     100 |    1234 |
|      20 |    1234 |    |     200 |    5678 |
|      30 |    5678 |    +---------+---------+
|      40 |    9876 |
+---------+---------+
```

The inner join queries will produce:

```
+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 |
+---------+---------+
|      10 |     100 |
|      20 |     100 |
+---------+---------+
```

An outer join query including the filter in the `on` clause will produce:

```
+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 |
+---------+---------+
|      10 |     100 |
|      20 |     100 |
|      30 |         |
|      40 |         |
+---------+---------+
```

whereas an outer join query with the filter after the join will produce:

```
+---------+---------+
| column1 | column2 |
+---------+---------+
|      10 |     100 |
|      20 |     100 |
+---------+---------+
```

Note that since `columna` is in both tables, you have to indicate which `columna` the filter is associated to. I assumed table1's.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborative answer, I spent some time to understand it yesterday and was able to make sense out of it. I really appreciate you taking the time out for explaining it and confirming my understanding as well.