# Connection between tables

Tags: mysql

I would like to know what is the best way to create a connection between two tables (or more).
I have seen two different ways to do so.

In the next example, I have 2 tables. **Table1** has customerId (key) and customerName. **Table2** has customerId (key) and CustomerPhone

table1:

```
 customerId | customerName|  
============+=============+
 1          |  Josh       |  
 2          |  Nadia      |
```

table2:

```
 customerId | customerPhone|  
============+==============+
 1          |  123         |  
 2          |  456         |
```

Which query is the best and why:

```
SELECT Table1.customerId, Table2.customerPhone  
FROM   Table1, Table2  
WHERE  Table1.customerId = Table2.customerId
```

Query2:

```
 SELECT Table1.customerId, Table2.customerPhone  
 FROM   Table1   
 Inner Join  Table2 ON Table1.customerId = Table2.customerId
```

Comment: If the key is unique in both tables, why isn't the data being stored in a single table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL left join vs multiple tables on FROM line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894490/sql-left-join-vs-multiple-tables-on-from-line)

Comment: the data isn't being stored in a single table for the example. @BenM

Answer (score 2):

The second option is more common and considered to be the right one, however they are both doing the same thing under the hood

Answer (score 1):

The first query makes first a cross join and then reduces the result to fit the where cflause.

The second matches the tables by check ing if the condition in the ON clause ist met.

Both do the same, but the first is slowe

Answer (score 1):

The first query is written using old syntax (SQL-89):

```
SELECT Table1.customerId, Table2.customerPhone  
FROM   Table1, Table2  
WHERE  Table1.customerId = Table2.customerId
```

The second query is written in modern syntax (SQL-92):

```
SELECT Table1.customerId, Table2.customerPhone  
FROM   Table1   
Inner Join  Table2 ON Table1.customerId = Table2.customerId
```

They are equivalent. Use SQL-92. Use SQL-92!

Comment: Why the downvote? Did I miss something?

Comment: I don't know why the downvote. thank you for your explanation. I would upvote, but I'm new and not able to do it yet.