# OUTER in LEFT OUTER JOIN MySQL

Tags: mysql, left-join

[In MS SQL-SERVER OUTER does not pay any role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-vs-left-outer-join-in-sql-server/4401540#4401540). Do it plays any role in MySQL?

Do these two request identical?:

```
SELECT Name as Customers
FROM Customers
LEFT OUTER JOIN Orders
ON Customers.Id = Orders.CustomerId
WHERE Orders.Id IS NULL
```

and

```
SELECT Name as Customers
FROM Customers
LEFT JOIN Orders
ON Customers.Id = Orders.CustomerId
WHERE Orders.Id IS NULL
```

I did not find information in [official documentation yet](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html).

Comment: ANSI SQL 92 defined it as `<join type> ::=
                INNER
              | <outer join type> [ OUTER ]
              | UNION

         <outer join type> ::=
                LEFT
              | RIGHT
              | FULL`

Comment: If you'll see this line at the documentaion `table_reference {LEFT|RIGHT} [OUTER] JOIN table_reference join_specification` which has `[OUTER]` as optional. So yeah in mysql as well -No difference.

Comment: `OUTER` is optional defined in ANSI/ISO SQL standards, how it is defined in a RDMS always check the RDMS manual ..Or do a test case where you run it with and without `OUTER` keyword to check and making sure..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between left join and left outer join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3940308/difference-between-left-join-and-left-outer-join)

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: @ambianBeing this is very uncommon that keys in square brackets have no any power. If compare with CLI notation for tools like Git. Have you got a link to article where I can read about syntax of MySQL documentation. Thank you

Comment: That is so interesting that in MySQL syntax time to time appears words that used just for information, like comments, I found one in functions.  And now I find one in JOINS.  What is more curious do square brackets always mark this kind of words? (In MS SQL answer Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen said that in MS SQL square brackets have influence time to time)

Answer (score 0):

They are identical in MySQL as well.