# Is 'LEFT OUTER JOIN' equivalent to 'JOIN' in Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

[On this MSDN page, it shows that these are equivelant;](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187518%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

> LEFT OUTER JOIN or LEFT JOIN

My question, in MSSQL is

```
JOIN
```

also equivalent to

```
LEFT JOIN
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` is not equal to `JOIN`.  The default `JOIN` is `INNER`.

Comment: Where in the document does it say `LEFT JOIN` is equivalent to `JOIN`?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

No.

`JOIN` is equivalent to `INNER JOIN`.

---

**Check [this example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/61229/join-example)**.
Since it returned the rows, we can assume it's an `INNER JOIN`.

**and [checking documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2005/ms177634(v=sql.90)):**

> INNER
>   Specifies all matching pairs of rows are returned. Discards unmatched rows from both tables. **When no join type is specified, this is the default.**

Also, according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-and-left-outer-join-in-sql-server), the type-part of the JOIN clause is optional:

> For instance, the entire type-part of the JOIN clause is optional, in
>   which case the default is INNER if you just specify JOIN.

Comment: I added the source of the actual quote

Answer (score 3):

> For instance, the entire type-part of the JOIN clause is optional, in
>   which case the default is INNER if you just specify JOIN.

-Source [LEFT JOIN vs. LEFT OUTER JOIN in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-and-left-outer-join-in-sql-server)

Comment: I believe my answer more directly answers the question but I can't accept my answer until two days have passed

Comment: if you say so. But I think you have made a question for a yes or no answer and I don't see a yes or no in your answer :P

Comment: Hey, fair enough, you include my answer as well plus then you get rep so win win.

Comment: you made a good point so I've edited my answer to add more info :)