# Two tables connected by foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I need to connect two tables in SQL Server: `Table A` has a primary key called `IDTableA` (`integer` field) and `Table B` has a primary key `IDTableB` (`integer` field as well).

`Table A` contains a foreign key `IDTableB` whereby I want to connect both tables, this field is of type `integer` and its value is 0.

My problem is that since there is no record in `Table B` whose ID is 0, do not show me those records from table A with a 0 stored in the foreign key.

The relationship between both tables is: a record in `Table A` may belong to one or no record in the table B. Therefore, the default value of the foreign key in table A is 0.

I tried connecting the tables with `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` but it does not work and left no records show. What I can do?.

Thanks.

My SQL statement:

```
Select TableA.* 
From TableA 
inner join TableB on TableA.IdTableB = TableB.IdTableB
```

The Solution:

```
    Select TableA.* 
    From TableA 
    LEFT JOIN TableB on TableA.IdTableB = TableB.IdTableB
```

More Info: 
[LEFT JOIN vs. LEFT OUTER JOIN in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-and-left-outer-join-in-sql-server)

Comment: can you post your query?

Comment: Left join is correct. You probably switched sides. Can you please post your query?

Comment: If the value of TableA.IDTableB is always 0, how do you expect it to connect to Table B (where there is no record whose ID is 0)?

Comment: There is the query published.

Comment: Mark Bannister, default value or IdTableB is 0, but his value could be any integer value.

Comment: The column in TableA referencing TableB should be nullable, and the default should be null, if you don't want to reference a row in TableB.

Comment: If you change "inner" to "left" your query will be fine. If you are still getting no rows, TableA is empty OR you have __where__ clause you did not share with us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use left join only

Something like this

```
Select *
from table_1 tbl1
left join table_2 tbl2 on tbl2.id = tbl1.id
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Owkei,did you try it something like this "Select TableA.* 
From TableA 
left join TableB on TableA.IdTableB = TableB.IdTableB",

Comment: Sorry but I had tried `LEFT OUTER JOIN` but not `LEFT JOIN`. That was the solution. Now works properly.

Comment: @MGG_Soft It is the same. Keyword OUTER may be omitted.

Comment: Here is the information: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-and-left-outer-join-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

An inner join is the most common join operation used in applications and can be regarded as the default join-type. Inner join creates a new result table by combining column values of two tables (A and B) based upon the join-predicate. The query compares each row of A with each row of B to find all pairs of rows which satisfy the join-predicate. When the join-predicate is satisfied, column values for each matched pair of rows of A and B are combined into a result row.

```
FROM Table A <renametablehere>
Inner Join Table B <renametablehere>
On <renamedtablename for A>.ID = <renamed table name for b>B.ID
```