# Why do we have OUTER clause in LEFT JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, join

What the difference between the 2 queries below

**UPDATE**

This question is already answered in a similar question here [LEFT JOIN vs. LEFT OUTER JOIN in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-and-left-outer-join-in-sql-server).

```
SELECT * FROM ca 
LEFT JOIN exam 
ON ca.subject = exam.subject
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM ca 
LEFT OUTER JOIN exam 
ON ca.subject = exam.subject
```

Tables

```
Table 'CA'
--------------------
subject|score
----------------
ENG    |25
MTH    |34
BIO    |18


Table 'Exam'
--------------------
subject|score
----------------
ENG    |25
```

Running the 2 queries produce the same result in mysql, sqlserver 2008. I didn't test in Oracle.

```
subject | score1 | subject | score1
--------------------------------------
ENG       14       ENG       44
MTH       28       NULL      NULL
BIO       22       NULL      NULL
```

What's the purpose of that OUTER clause

Comment: See this SO post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-and-left-outer-join-in-sql-server

Comment: I didn't see that one. This one (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/sql-difference-between-inner-and-outer-join) that I saw was confusing

Comment: Is this question on some new exam or brain bench or something? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19005/difference-of-left-join-and-left-outer-join

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no difference. The `OUTER` keyword is optional.

Answer (score 2):

They are equivalent in the sense that all LEFT JOIN queries are also LEFT OUTER JOIN.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Outer_joins for more information.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between `LEFT` and `LEFT OUTER`; the `OUTER` keyword may be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

In some databases LEFT JOIN is called LEFT OUTER JOIN,so it's the same thing.  The keyword OUTER is optional So, remind yourself that it's an outer join.

The keyword LEFT, RIGHT, or FULL is mandatory. Left, right, and full outer joins are the only types of outer join. And of course the keyword JOIN is mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

There are four types of joins: inner, left outer, right outer and full outer. Left join, right join and full join are simply abbreviations for the types of outer joins.

Comment: And anti-joins, semi-joins, and then there is the distinction between equijoins and non-equijoins.