# What is the difference between LEFT OUTER JOIN and LEFT JOIN? Result is the same

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Left join and Left outer join in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-and-left-outer-join-in-sql-server)

Today my question is about the join operations in oracle, 
I have two tables `Table1` and `Tabel2` 
Now I would like to perform join operations on them,
When I perform left outer join I get the result that is correct
and when I perform left join then I get the result that is correct

On both the operation I get the same result,

Now my question is that what is the difference between left outer join and left join.

Why oracle provided Left Outer Join when Left Join works the same way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-and-left-outer-join-in-sql-server - this is how its is defined in standard SQL. LEFT/RIGHT/FULL joins are always "OUTER" joins.

Comment: See: http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-2003-2.bnf.html#joined%20table