# Why is OUTER optional in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ansi-sql

Referring to this post on [**Stack Overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-and-left-outer-join-in-sql-server/406333?noredirect=1#comment23719011_406333)

Why was the key word `OUTER` made optional (in `LEFT OUTER JOIN` etc) - if it had been a required word then scripts written on SQL Server would be more standard compliant?

Comment: Note that `INNER` is equally optional, but in that case, including it can help make queries more readable.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about it refers to another question and you need that other question to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is optional in ANSI SQL, not just in T-SQL.
And it is optional, because the joins are unambiguous without the use of `OUTER`.

Comment: +1 thanks Daniel - I should have done a little research first! - referring to Date and Darwin "the optional OUTER is a mere noiseword and has no effect on the overall meaning of the expression"