# only select/count verified and not banned users

Tags: php, sql, count

Here is the code

```
SELECT username,count(username) FROM users WHERE status = '1' // $vuser to get the verified user only (it's the main query)

SELECT username FROM banned_users WHERE username = $vuser  // if yes $bad_user is true else false
```

Does it possible to only  select/count verified users who doesn't exist in the banned_users with one sql query ?

Any idea please ?

Comment: There are many users with same `username` ?

Comment: use inner join on userid

Comment: @ CORRUPT each user have a unique username

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT u.username, count(u.username) 
FROM users u
left outer join banned_users b on b.username = u.username
WHERE u.status = '1'
AND b.username is null
GROUP BY u.username
```

Comment: I made a little change to my Q,could you check it again please ? thank you.

Comment: @user2203703: I updated my answer and added a `group by` clause.

Comment: does it possible to use any other join case ? what about inner join ?

Comment: You have to use a `left join`. See [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) for a good explanation.

Comment: I know i'm asking to much..but i swear i tried left join before i open the Q and din't work with me and i thought it not possible to do that..could you please add + the left join case to your answer please ? thank you.

Comment: I used the left join in my answer. `left join` is the same as `left outer join`

Comment: They are the same. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-and-left-outer-join-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

Try with nested query:

```
SELECT username, COUNT(username) // Selects the `username` and `COUNT(username)` columns
FROM users // From the `users` table
WHERE status = '1' // Where its `status` is '1'
AND username NOT IN (SELECT b.username FROM banned_users b) // And its `username` is not at `username` column in the `banned_users` table
```

Comment: Using a JOIN is likely to be a more efficient query than using IN/NOT IN