# Performance issue in update query

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlperformance

I have one small doubt in query performance. Basically, I have a table with more than 1C records. `sl_id` is the primary key in that table. Currently, I am updating the table column `status` to `true` (default `false`) by using the `sl_id`.

In my program, I will have 200 unique `sl_id` in an array. I am updating the `status` to `true`(always) by using each `sl_id`.

**My doubt:**

Shall I use individual update queries by specifing each `sl_id` in a where condition to update the status?

(OR)

Shall I use `IN` operator and put all 200 unique `sl_id` in one single query?

Which one will be faster?

Comment: Are you asking if you should run 1 query for 200 rows or 200 queries for 1 row each?

Comment: @shree.pat18, Yes. That is my doubt.

Answer (score 57):

In rough order of slower to faster:

- 200 Individual queries, each in their own transaction
- 200 Individual queries, all in one transaction
- 1 big query with `WHERE ... IN (...)` or `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ...)`
- 1 big query with an `INNER JOIN` over a `VALUES` clause
- (only faster for very big lists of values): `COPY` value list to a temp table, index it, and `JOIN` on the temp table.

If you're using hundreds of values I really suggest joining over a `VALUES` clause. For many thousands of values, `COPY` to a temp table and index it then join on it.

An example of joining on a values clause. Given this `IN` query:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE somevalue IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

the equivalent with `VALUES` is:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
INNER JOIN (
  VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)
) vals(v)
ON (somevalue = v);
```

Note, however, that using `VALUES` this way is a PostgreSQL extension, wheras `IN`, or using a temporary table, is SQL standard.

See this related question:

- [Postgres NOT IN performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17813492/398670)

Comment: The `values` clause as you have shown is defined in the standard if I'm not mistaken (not 100% about the alias with the column definition though - but that could be turned into a CTE if standard compliance was important)

Comment: `VALUES` is standard, sure. I don't think it's SQL-spec to use it as a statement in a subquery though. Certainly it hasn't worked in non-PostgreSQL DBs I've tried it with. Nor as a top-level statement like Pg permits - `VALUES (1)` is a legal PostgreSQL query.

Comment: `select * from ( values (1), (2) ) t (id)` works (at least) in SQL Server 2012 and DB2.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That's really good to know, thankyou for testing. I think it was MySQL and Oracle I was trying with.

Comment: Btw: for a simple test table (150k rows) the `in` solution was faster for me than the join with `values`: http://explain.depesz.com/s/9rkR vs. http://explain.depesz.com/s/7WL `not in` however was substantially slower than the left join/is null solution

Comment: *`VALUES` conforms to the SQL standard. LIMIT and OFFSET are PostgreSQL extensions.* http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-values.html

Comment: There's a syntax error in the second query.  Instead of WHERE, it should be ON.

Comment: One other thing to consider is the load impact on your DB.  I had a very frequently used query where the number of values varied from 5-30,000.  When testing different approaches on the 30K values, using a temp table was a little bit faster than joining on values but had a much larger impact on the server's CPU load.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely you should use `WHERE IN` operator. Making 200 queries is much slower than one bigger. Remember, when you sending query to database, there is additional time needed to communicate between server and DB and this will crush your performance.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely IN is more powerful, but again the number of match to check in IN will make performance issue.

So, I will suggest to use IN but with BATCH, as in if you have 200 record to update then part in 50 each and then make 4 UPDATE query, or something like that.

Hope it helps...!!