# JPA: How to create a query to join on values list?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jpa, jpql, hibernate-criteria

I have a query where I expect 1000s of rows and I'm looking for values in two columns. Something like this

```sql
select
  *
from
  foo
WHERE
 (name, version)
in
  (('a','2.0.0'),('b','1.0.0'));
```

Then I learned that this is not possible in JPA and I converted the query to multiple `OR` and `AND` queries.

```sql
select
  *
from
  foo
WHERE
  name = 'a' and version = '2.0.0'
  or name = 'b' and version = '1.0.0'
```

I'm using a specification to build the query.

```java
      var predicates =
          values.entrySet().stream()
              .map(
                  entry -> {
                    return cb.and(
                        cb.equal(root.get("name"),entry.getKey()),
                        cb.equal(root.get("version"), entry.getValue()));
                  })
              .toList();

      return cb.or(predicates.toArray(Predicate[]::new));
```

That works but it's very slow and other answer support my findings.

- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91247/optimizing-a-postgres-query-with-a-large-in
- [Performance issue in update query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647503/performance-issue-in-update-query)
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/129844/cross-product-between-table-column-and-input-values

So now I'm trying to do something like this.

```sql
select
  *
from
(
    values
        ('a', '2.0.0'),
        ('b', '1.0.0')
) t(name, version)
left join
  foo
on t.name = foo.name and t.version = foo.version
```

Here is the official documentation.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-values.html

I'm having trouble translating this in to JPA or using a specification / criteria builder.

Any ideas? Or do I have to use a native query?

Thank you!

Comment: In my hands your specification-built query works well.  What version of PostgreSQL are you using and what indexes do you have?

Comment: select
  *
from
  foo
WHERE
  `(`name = 'a' and version = '2.0.0' `)`
  or `(`name = 'b' and version = '1.0.0'`)`

is missing parenthesis.

Comment: Or: `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE name & version IN ('a2.0.0', 'b1.0.0')`

Comment: The parenthesis aren't necessary. Check the operator precedence https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-PRECEDENCE.