# Hibernate run IN (VALUES ...) rather than IN query

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have a huge number of entities i need to load from the DB, i have a query like this

```
FROM ${entityName} x WHERE x.id IN :ids
```

the above generates SQL queries like this: `... where EntityName.id in (? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ...)`
This is incredibly slow for large `ids` sets. Multiple posts here have suggested instead to run an `IN VALUES` query like this:

```
... where EntityName.id in (VALUES (?) , (?) , (?) , (?) , (?) , (?) , (?) , (?) , ...)
```

Here is my Java:

```
List<T> result = entityManager.createQuery(queryString, queryEntity)
    .setParameter("ids", batch)
    .getResultList()
```

Wondering how i can get hibernate to do that?
Do i need to specify that in the HQL somehow?
I tried this not expecting it to work, and it didn't.
`SELECT x FROM ${entityName} x WHERE x.id IN (VALUES :ids)`

Is this even possible in HQL, or do i need to write a native query?

Comment: What database is this? *Which* posts recommend this?

Comment: using postgreSql. And poste like these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813492/postgres-not-in-performance, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24647503/performance-issue-in-update-query

Answer (score 0):

I mean, look, you *can* in principle do this extremely easily by just passing a native SQL query to `createNativeQuery()`.

But you really need to ask yourself:

> what am I even doing here?

If you have such a huge quantity of ids that there are too many for Postgres to handle them efficiently in an `in` predicate, then it's highly unlikely that pulling all that state into the JVM and materializing entity objects to represent all those rows is an efficient or reasonable thing to do.

If you absolutely *have* to do this, make sure you use `StatelessSession`.

But have you considered using a stored procedure or something like that?