# how many arguments can be used with the IN clause in postgresql?

Tags: java, database, postgresql, jdbc

I am executing a query in postgresql database from a java program, and the query is like:

```
SELECT ... FROM table_name WHERE column_name IN("<list of values>");
```

the problem is that the list of values is created dynamically and there is no limit to its size, and when this list is getting too big I am getting a PSQLException with the message: stack depth length exceeded.
my question is how do I determine how many arguments can I use with the IN clause before this exception happens? let's say the max_stack_depth is 2MB, can I use that to determine how many arguments can I use with the IN clause?

Comment: Did you try `column_name IN("<first list of values>") OR column_name IN("<second list of values>")`? Does it let you pass more items? I used this trick to work around a problem in Oracle. I am not sure if it is going to work with Postgresql.

Comment: Do the values come from same database even if from other tables ?

Comment: you are right, this can be helpful, I want to eventually do something like that, but my problem is what is the maximum length allowed for <first list of values> and for <second list of values> before I exceed the stack depth limit, my problem is with calculating that threshold at which I am going to break my list into two, and I couldn't really find anything helpful on the internet about it... can you help me with it?

Comment: Serge, if the values came from the same database I would have made a join, but actually the values are read from an external file... so no way to join, unless I insert them in a temporary table and I am trying to avoid that because I don't think the performance would be very good.

Comment: Please show the full exception text, and your PostgreSQL version from `SELECT version()`.

Comment: dear craig, that's the postgre version: PostgreSQL 8.4.20 on x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, compiled by GCC gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4), 64-bit

Comment: , and as for the exception: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: stack depth limit exceeded at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1531) at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1313) at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:188) at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:452) at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:354)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do an `inner join` to a `values` table

```
select ...
from
    table_name
    inner join
    (values
        (first_value), (second_value)
    ) s(column_name) using (column_name)
;
```

Or, easier to string build, to an unnested array

```
select ...
from
    table_name
    inner join
    unnest(
        array[first_value, second_value]
    ) s(column_name) using (column_name)
;
```

Comment: A `values` list is likely to be a lot faster, though. For very big lists you can even create a temp table. I wrote some more about it a while ago - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17038097/398670

Comment: that's a brilliant solution... I haven't thought of this... thank you very much :) although I still don't know the limit of the list for the IN clause, but changing my query into this is actually better than dividing into many lists or inserting into temporary table :) I am gonna use this solution... thnx ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using 7.4 or earlier, it depends on the `max_expr_depth` setting (or `max_stack_depth` in newer I believe).

You can always check it's value:

```
test=> SHOW max_expr_depth;
```

And change

```
test=> SET max_expr_depth TO 10;
```

Then you can operate on this value.

[Found HERE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/runtime-config.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CLIENT-OTHER)

> The default value of 10000 is high enough for any normal query, but
>   you can raise it if needed. (But if you raise it too high, you run the
>   risk of server crashes due to stack overflow.)

This is not the best solution for your problem, but I believe it answers your question.

Comment: ... but if you're using 7.4 or earlier, you're probably also half-way to fossilised, though.

Comment: that is why I mentioned `max_stack_depth` property (replacement for `max_expr_depth`)

Comment: thnx a lot guys for your help, I actually increased the max_depth as a temporary solution but now I am trying to optimize my program so I don't need that increment... that's why I wanted know the maximum number of allowed parameters for the IN clause... but really thnx, I appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 1):

When you fear that there might be a huge number of values in the `in` clause, you can use a temporary table.

You create a temporary table with one column and an index on that column. Before the query, you put your data for the `in` clause as rows in the temporary table. Then you execute the query, using one of the following contructs:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name in (SELECT column_name FROM temptable);
SELECT * FROM table_name a JOIN temptable b ON (a.column_name = b.column_name);
SELECT * FROM table_name a WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM temptable t WHERE a.column_name=t.column_name);
```

There won't be a problem with parallel running queries: Contents in a temporary table written by one session are invisible to any other session.

The big advantage with this approach is, that the SQL parses does not have to produce all you values. The structure of the query stays the same, you can even use a prepared statement. This together with the usage of an index can be a huge performance boost.

Comment: The cost of creating the index is bigger than a sequential scan and the probability of it being used is small.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto With lots of rows in the table and very few RAM the index might be used and it might be faster (using a merge join, as the index is already sorted). Alternatively a bitmap index might be useful.