# Join 3 tables and Group

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am stuck here working on a homework and this is what I have got.

Instruction is: Display department name, city and number of different jobs in each department.
tables employees (has job_id and department_id), deptos (has location_id, department_id but no job ids), locations (has location_id and city)
I need to include all cities even the ones without employees

What I was trying to do...

```
select d.department_name, l.city, count (distinct e.job_id)
from employees e
join deptos d on (e.department_id=d.department_id)
join locations l on (d.location_id=l.location_id)
group by d.department_name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

locations can have data missing in other tables, so right join or you start from it and use left joins. You also need to group by city. Tried to do minimum changes to OP query.

```
select d.department_name, l.city, count(distinct e.job_id)
from employees e
join deptos d on (e.department_id=d.department_id)
right join locations l on (d.location_id=l.location_id)
group by d.department_name, l.city
```

[SQL Fiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/36c00/14/0)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a OUTER JOIN to accomplish this... like the below. You do not necessarily have to use the keyword outer as it is implied, just remember the the difference between using LEFT and RIGHT joins there is a post on that here. Example below

[LEFT JOIN vs. LEFT OUTER JOIN in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-and-left-outer-join-in-sql-server)

```
select d.department_name, l.city, count (distinct e.job_id)
from locations l
left outer join deptos d on (e.department_id=d.department_id)
left outer join employees e on (d.location_id=l.location_id)
group by d.department_name
```

Comment: join conditions need to be swapped and group by missing l.city

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT locations.city, deptos.department_name, 
       Count(DISTINCT employees.job_id) AS DiffJobsDeptCount
FROM employees 
     RIGHT JOIN (deptos 
     RIGHT JOIN locations 
     ON deptos.location_id = locations.location_id) 
     ON employees.department_id  = deptos.department_id
GROUP BY locations.city, deptos.department_name
```

Comment: In the OP question, there is `count (distinct e.job_id)` in the query :)

Comment: **@Fabien TheSolution**, hey that is where the employees table comes into play.  Missed that one.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Does not display city without departments as OP wanted. Either needs to be RIGHT JOIN twice or without brackets.