# Clarification about joins in SQL and where you can reference aliases

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

This is a part of my query:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN hz_cust_acct_sites_all acct ON acct.party_site_id = hzps.party_site_id 

LEFT OUTER JOIN hz_cust_site_uses_all site ON site.cust_acct_site_id = acct.cust_acct_site_id
                                          AND site.site_use_code = 'BILL_TO'
```

Is it OK to reference acct in the second `LEFT OUTER JOIN` statement? How does scope work for SQL.

Thanks!

Comment: The `OUTER` part is usless/not needed.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO - OK thanks, I will remove

Comment: OUTER is a style preference.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-and-left-outer-join-in-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is technically allowed to have optional part of optional part

EDIT: 
Still I am in doubt I understood question correctly. 
I guessed it is about OUTER JOIN chaining.

Consider this example:

```
create table t1 ( a int, b int ); 
create table t2 ( a int, b int ); 
create table t3 ( a int, b int ); 

insert into t1 values ( 1, 10 ); 
insert into t1 values ( 2, 20 ); 
insert into t1 values ( 3, 30 ); 

insert into t2 values ( 10, 100 ); 
insert into t2 values ( 20, 200 ); 

insert into t3 values ( 100, 1000 ); 
insert into t3 values ( 300, 3000 );
```

Below query

```
select t1.a, t2.b t2_b, t3.b t3_b
from 
  T1 
    left join t2 on ( t1.b = t2.a ) 
    left join t3 on ( t2.b = t3.a ) 
order by 1, 2, 3
```

would get:

```
A   T2_B    T3_B
1   100 1000    ==> here all linked.OK
2   200 (null)  ==> here just T2_B got, but no link to T3. 
3   (null)  (null)  ==> no elements to bring from T2, T3
```

Also as 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f61f6/5

Comment: Please provide a more detail as to why it's *technically allowed*

Comment: joins are parsed in the order they appear