# What advantages are gained from saying Left Outer Join over Left Join

Tags: sql, join, left-join, outer-join

If Left Outer Join and Left join do the same exact thing. Are there any advantages 
to use one over the other? What scenarios might you choose to say Left Join over Left Outer Join or vice versa?

Comment: Um....You wouldn't? If you are positive, RI is enforced, etc, there is no reason.

Comment: They are semantically same. Second just short form of first.

Comment: `Outer` is merely optional, as is `Inner` from `Inner Join`.  It's purely preference by whomever is writing it.

Comment: Unless some DBMS allows only one the two syntaxes, it is purely preference.

Comment: I do it for readability.  It helps clearly distinguish INNER and OUTER joins when I'm glancing at it

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-and-left-outer-join-in-sql-server?rq=1

Comment: Lots of SQL terms are optional... ([`outer`], [`inner`], [`as`], `Insert [into]`, `delete [From] tablename`, etc...  and so it depends on whether you like shorter terse code that requires less effort to read, or longer, redundant code that is does not require as much familiarity to read correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keywords `inner` and `outer` are optional (like many others). The join type is implied:

- unqualified = inner
- `left` = outer
- `right` = outer
- `full` or `cross` = outer

I personally never use them as they are code clutter.

Answer (score 1):

They are exactly the same. The outer join is optional.

HOWEVER, If you do not specify an Outer join type: Left, Right, or Full, then it will be an INNER join.

In the context of Left/Right they are equivalent to an OUTER join and therefore OUTER will be defaulted, and can, semantically be added.

Left Join == Left outer join

Like some people have said, it's very nice for the readability.

Comment: unless you mistyped your second sentence,  "HOWEVER, ..." you are incorrect. If you say `left`, `right`, or `full`, then `outer` is implied.  a bare `join` without qualifiers, implies `inner`.

Comment: Yes, thank you I have added in more explanation.

Comment: sorry, but as it reads, it is still incorrect... It should read "HOWEVER, If you do not specify an Outer join type: `Left`, `Right`, or `Full`, then it will be an `INNER` join".

Comment: I have removed my downvote