# SQL Where ID equals ID but can be null

Tags: sql, where-clause

I'm trying to fetch some data from an db. I've got an `Taak` table with an possible `idPartij` column. Possible, because it can be an real `idPartij`, but can also be `null`.

The query I've got:

```
SELECT T.idTaak,
       T.Taaktype,
       P.Partijnaam,
       T.Naar,
       T.UltimatumDatum,
       T.Opmerking,
       T.Status,
       T.Prioriteit
FROM Taak AS T,
     Partij AS P
WHERE T.idPartij = P.idPartij
ORDER BY idTaak DESC
```

This is working fine when I've got an id in `T.idPartij`, but as mentioned earlier, that id can be `null`. And when that is the case, the row won't be in the result.

Only problem: When I remove the where clause, I get the rows a lot ( because the `Partij` table isn't filtered anymore...

I'm an total noob at SQL, so i can't think of an way to "fix" this problem. Only thing i can think of is creating 2 query's, but i don't think that is an nice way to do...

Comment: @GuillemoMansilla, didn't thought of it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are trying to link two tables, you should use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT T.idTaak,
       T.Taaktype,
       P.Partijnaam,
       T.Naar,
       T.UltimatumDatum,
       T.Opmerking,
       T.Status,
       T.Prioriteit
FROM Taak AS T LEFT OUTER JOIN Partij AS P
   ON T.idPartij = P.idPartij
ORDER BY idTaak DESC
```

If you don't want to include the `NULL` values use an `INNER JOIN` instead.

Note that you should not use these old-style-joins [it's a bad habit to kick](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

---

According to the `NULL` issue:

You cannot use `= NULL` or `<> NULL` because `NULL` is not equal or unequal to anything. `NULL` means unknown.

So use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`:

```
WHERE T.idPartij IS NULL OR T.idPartij = P.idPartij
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> A value of NULL indicates that the value is unknown. A value of NULL
> is different from an empty or zero value. No two null values are
> equal. Comparisons between two null values, or between a NULL and any
> other value, return unknown because the value of each NULL is unknown.

Comment: I've copy passed your statement, but i still get an big list with all the `Partij`en with the same `Taak`

Comment: @Mathlight:  i've overlooked first that you're trying to ink two tables. Use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead. I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: The left outer join did indeed the trick. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify a database platform, so it is safe to use ANSI syntax.

Do a `coalesce` to compare `P.idPartij` when `T.idPartij` is `null`:

```
where P.idPartij = coalesce(T.idPartij, P.idPartij)
```

It will match all `T` rows if `T.idPartij` is `null`.

If you want to return no `T` row when `idPartij` is `null`, use a `left outer join`:

```
from   Taak t
left
outer
join   Partij p
on     t.idPartij = p.idPartij
```

Comment: Where do i insert this in the query?

Comment: @TMNT2014: you are right. It was the other way around.

Comment: @Mathlight: In the `where` clause.

Comment: Maybe it's me, but when i copy paste your code into my query, it's not working...

Comment: I'm sorry. I meant that I still get an big list. But an `LEFT OUT JOIN` solved the problem. Thank you anyway for helping me!

Comment: That is true. If it doesn't match, it matches all. This works if the use case is right. Otherwise, you should indeed use `left outer join`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of inner join you need to use left join to get the missing rows.

```
WHERE T.idPartij = P.idPartij OR T.idPartij IS NULL
```

Comment: I still get an big list with the Taak (that has an null `idPartij` ) multiplied by all `Partijen`

Comment: In that case you can use LEFT OUTER JOIN (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-and-left-outer-join-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join the tables so that (a) non-null equivalent Ids match, and (b) null Ids match, then you're query should look like:

```
SELECT T.idTaak,
       T.Taaktype,
       P.Partijnaam,
       T.Naar,
       T.UltimatumDatum,
       T.Opmerking,
       T.Status,
       T.Prioriteit
FROM Taak AS T INNER JOIN Partij AS P
   ON T.idPartij = P.idPartij OR T.idPartij IS NULL AND P.idPartij IS NULL
ORDER BY idTaak DESC
```

Comment: an `LEFT OUTER JOIN` worked for me. If I understand it right [from here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins) does an left outer join return an null instead of nothing. And i want an null...

Comment: Use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to return rows that match on the left hand side regardless if any rows match on the right side.  I wasn't sure from your question if you were trying to match rows that exist on both sides where both have null `idPartij`.

Comment: Alright, thank you for the clarification. Now I'm sure I need the `LEFT OUTER`.