# Selecting items with join and without foreign key

Tags: php, laravel

I have query which gets each user's record from blacklist table and relations to them from rules table.

It looks like that:

```
$result1 = DB::table('blacklist')
        ->join('rules', 'blacklist.rule_id', '=', 'rules.id')
        ->select('blacklist.*', 'rules.clicks', 'rules.minutes')
        ->groupBy('blacklist.address')
        ->where('blacklist.user_id', JWTAuth::user()->id)
        ->get();
```

However I set field blacklist.rule_id as CAN BE NULL. Above query doesn't get records which have blacklist.rule_id == null(only these with values).

I have second query for that purpose:

```
$result2 = DB::table('blacklist')
            ->select('blacklist.*')
            ->groupBy('blacklist.address')
            ->where('blacklist.user_id', JWTAuth::user()->id)
            ->where('blacklist.rule_id', null)
            ->get();
```

But how to do it in one query?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24533406/sql-where-id-equals-id-but-can-be-null this seems to tackle your problem. A left outer join should be working for you - together with an adapted where method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is actually an `leftJoin` instead of `join`:

```
$result1 = DB::table('blacklist')
    ->leftJoin('rules', 'blacklist.rule_id', '=', 'rules.id')
    ->select('blacklist.*', 'rules.clicks', 'rules.minutes')
    ->groupBy('blacklist.address')
    ->where('blacklist.user_id', JWTAuth::user()->id)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$result2 = DB::table('blacklist')
                ->select('blacklist.*')
                ->groupBy('blacklist.address')
                ->where(function ($result2) {
                $result2->where('blacklist.user_id', JWTAuth::user()->id)
                    ->orWhereNull('blacklist.user_id');
            }
                ->get();
```