# Multiple left joins in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, join

I am trying to convert a SQL query to LINQ and am having trouble with getting the syntax correct.  My original (working) SQL query is:

```
 SELECT a.PersonnelNumber,
    a.LastName,
    a.FirstName,
    a.MiddleInitial,
    b.Title,
    b.Division,
    b.Section,
    b.Unit,
    d.PersonnelNumber AS SupervisorPersonnelNumber
FROM Person a
     JOIN Position b ON a.PositionID = b.PositionID
     LEFT JOIN Position c ON b.SupervisorPositionID = c.PositionID
     LEFT JOIN Person d ON c.PositionID = d.PositionID
```

I converted that into the following LINQ:

```
var query = from a in ctx.People
            from b in ctx.Positions.Where(b => a.PositionID == b.PositionID)
            from c in ctx.Positions.Where(c => b.SupervisorPositionID == c.PositionID).DefaultIfEmpty()
            from d in ctx.People.Where(d => c.PositionID == d.PositionID).DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { 
                            a.PersonnelNumber, 
                            a.LastName, 
                            a.FirstName, 
                            a.MiddleInitial, 
                            b.Title, 
                            b.Division, 
                            b.Section, 
                            b.Unit, 
                            SupervisorPersonnelNumber = d.PersonnelNumber
                       };
```

This returned way more results than I was anticipating (20000+ instead of ~1100) so I looked at the generated SQL:

```
SELECT 
[Extent2].[PositionID] AS [PositionID], 
[Extent1].[PersonnelNumber] AS [PersonnelNumber], 
[Extent1].[LastName] AS [LastName], 
[Extent1].[FirstName] AS [FirstName], 
[Extent1].[MiddleInitial] AS [MiddleInitial], 
[Extent2].[Title] AS [Title], 
[Extent2].[Division] AS [Division], 
[Extent2].[Section] AS [Section], 
[Extent2].[Unit] AS [Unit], 
[Extent4].[PersonnelNumber] AS [PersonnelNumber1]
FROM    [dbo].[Person] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Position] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[PositionID] = [Extent2].[PositionID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Position] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[SupervisorPositionID] = [Extent3].[PositionID]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Person] AS [Extent4] ON ([Extent3].[PositionID] = [Extent4].[PositionID]) OR (([Extent3].[PositionID] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[PositionID] IS NULL))
```

The last line of this is what is causing my issue:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Person] AS [Extent4] ON ([Extent3].[PositionID] = [Extent4].[PositionID]) OR (([Extent3].[PositionID] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[PositionID] IS NULL))
```

I wasn't sure why the additional `OR` clause was added on and removing it returned the desired results.

In case it helps, the `Position` table has (effectively, though not enforced) a 1:1 relationship with `Person` and `Position` has a relationship to itself: `PositionID` is FK to `SupervisorPositionID`

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Position](
[PositionID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[PositionNumber] [varchar](8) NULL,
[Title] [varchar](40) NULL,
[Division] [varchar](40) NULL,
[Section] [varchar](40) NULL,
[Unit] [varchar](40) NULL,
[SupervisorPositionID] [int] NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person](
[PersonID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[PersonnelNumber] [varchar](8) NOT NULL,
[LastName] [varchar](40) NULL,
[FirstName] [varchar](40) NULL,
[MiddleInitial] [char](1) NULL,
[PositionID] [int] NULL,
)
```

Why is `OR (([Extent3].[PositionID] IS NULL) AND ([Extent4].[PositionID] IS NULL))` being appended to the end of this line and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Why don't you use [join operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb311040.aspx)?

Comment: I'm open to any suggestions.  Do you have an example?  I only did it this way because this got me closer to my desired results than any of the other ways I tried.

Comment: What if you try: `ctx.People.Where(d => c.PositionID == d.PositionID.Value).DefaultIfEmpty()` ?

Comment: @Magnus No luck.  Same SQL is generated with same results.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the setting on your DbContext. The property is [UseDatabaseNullSemantics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.usedatabasenullsemantics(v=vs.113).aspx) and you need to set it to false

```
context.Configuration.UseDatabaseNullSemantics = false;
```

Comment: No luck.  This generated the same SQL and same results.

Comment: Setting this property to False produced the same results.  I also tried to set the `Nullable` property of `SupervisorPositionID` to `False` in the .edmx and that did not work either.

Comment: Since the `SupervisorPositionID` is an `INT` the "null" values are coming through as zeroes.  Perhaps that is part of the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any tools at the moment to check if this will produce the required output, but i think it should be close enough:

```
            from a in Persons
            join b in Positions on a.PositionID equals b.PositionID
            join c in Positions on b.SupervisorPositionID equals c.PositionID into SupervisorsPositions
                from c in SupervisorsPositions.DefaultIfEmpty()
            join d in Persons on c.PositionID equals d.PositionID into PersonalNumbers
                from d in PersonalNumbers.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { 
                            a.PersonnelNumber, 
                            a.LastName, 
                            a.FirstName, 
                            a.MiddleInitial, 
                            b.Title, 
                            b.Division, 
                            b.Section, 
                            b.Unit, 
                            SupervisorPersonnelNumber = d.PersonnelNumber
                       }
```

This query will produce:

```
SELECT [t0].[PersonnelNumber], [t0].[LastName], [t0].[FirstName], [t0].[MiddleInitial], [t1].[Title], [t1].[Division], [t1].[Section], [t1].[Unit], [t3].[PersonnelNumber] AS [SupervisorPersonnelNumber]
FROM [Person] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [Position] AS [t1] ON [t0].[PositionID] = ([t1].[PositionID])
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Position] AS [t2] ON [t1].[SupervisorPositionID] = ([t2].[PositionID])
LEFT OUTER JOIN [Person] AS [t3] ON ([t2].[PositionID]) = [t3].[PositionID]
```

By [T-SQL language specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634%28SQL.90%29.aspx) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN is equal to LEFT JOIN.
INNER JOIN is equal to JOIN.

So that query produces the result that you require. See [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-and-left-outer-join-in-sql-server) for more information about Join types in T-SQL.

Comment: This produces the same results.