# C# Linq Left Outer Join

Tags: c#, linq

When allUserDepart is null other join fire a exception on line of join allDepartment. Because uD its null. How to fix this code?

```
join d in allDepartment on uD.DepartmentId equals d.DepartmentId into departmentJoin
```

--Ful Code is

```
var data = (from us in allUsers
                        join uR in allUserRoles on us.UserId equals uR.UserId into userRoleJoin
                        from uR in userRoleJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join r in allRoles on uR.RoleId equals r.RoleId 
                        join uD in allUserDepartment on us.UserId equals uD.NewUserId into userDepJoin 
                        from uD in userDepJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join d in allDepartment on uD.DepartmentId equals d.DepartmentId into departmentJoin
                        from d in departmentJoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LEFT OUTER JOIN in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25315548/multiple-left-joins-in-linq

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to SQL multiple tables left outer join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142151/linq-to-sql-multiple-tables-left-outer-join)