# MySQL JOIN "WHEN"- is such a thing possible?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Background:

- I'm running a query which gets the total *widgets*, *sprockets*, and *gizmos* ordered by the customer during the last month
- I also have a *Total Orders* column which runs a subquery counting every order in that month
- The reason I do *Total Orders* in a subquery, instead of just adding the three columns, is because I also have a further two *Total Orders* columns for the two previous months
- I have an *orders* table that stores financial records, and separate tables for actual product details for *widgets*, *sprockets*, and *gizmos*

The problem:

- Occasionally, a *widget* might be 'half-deleted' (don't ask!) - where it has an *orders* record, but not a corresponding *widgets* record
- I do not want to count this in the *Total Widgets* column - which is easy enough, as I just do a `JOIN`
- However, I also do not want to count this in the *Total Orders* column...

My current query looks like this for *Total Widgets*:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(orders.id)
FROM orders
JOIN widgets ON widgets.id = orders.item_id
WHERE orders.product_id = 1 -- Product ID 1 is a Widget
AND orders.date BETWEEN "2014-09-01 00:00:00" AND "2014-09-30 23:59:59"
```

So this will get all 'accurate' widgets, with an intact `widget` table record.

Here is my current query for *Total Orders*:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(orders.id) AS count
FROM orders
JOIN widgets ON widgets.id = orders.item_id AND orders.product_id = 1
WHERE orders.date BETWEEN "2014-09-01 00:00:00" AND "2014-09-30 23:59:59"
```

So my thinking is that the above query should only `JOIN` when the order has a `product_id` of 1. However, it `JOIN`s in every case. Which means if we've ordered 10 widgets (2 of which have been half-deleted), 5 sprockets, and 5 gizmos, rather than showing 18 orders, it only shows 8. Changing to a `LEFT JOIN` shows 20, which is still wrong, it should be 18.

Hopefully the above makes sense - thanks in advance.

Comment: so... it's really early for me.  can you post some sample data from each table (with some data that will be returned and some that won't) and an example result set..?

Comment: Are you new, semi-new to SQL.  I only skimmed your question, but it sounds to me like you want to use an `OUTER JOIN`.  The following link is an answer for SQL Server, but basic SQL is mostly the same across architectures.  This should help you. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-and-left-outer-join-in-sql-server)

Comment: i am so confused. sorry, it's early.  you don't need a `sum(case)`... okay so... the straight join doesn't work because you filter for orders.product_id = 1 and so it won't count sprockets or gizmos. just widgets. and if you have 2 half deleted, but 10 on record... 8 is the correct answer. the left outer join lets it join on rows where product_id <> 1, too, so all rows from orders (which contains order records on widgets, sprockets, gizmos - half deleted or not). but this also allows those 2 half deleted rows

Comment: so... why don't you just do a straight join?  if you want the answer 18, just join orders and products and count it.  do not filter for widgets only.  do not do a left outer if you don't want half deleted.

Answer (score 0):

okay so... the straight join doesn't work because you filter for `orders.product_id = 1` and so it won't count sprockets or gizmos.  just widgets.  and if you have 2 half deleted, but 10 on record... 8 is the correct answer.  the `left outer join` lets it join on rows where `product_id <> 1`, too, so all rows from `orders` (which contains order records on widgets, sprockets, gizmos - half deleted or not).  but this also allows those 2 half deleted rows.

why don't you just do a straight join? if you want the answer 18, just join orders and products and count it. do not filter for widgets only. do not do a left outer if you don't want half deleted.

```
create table product (
   product_id int,
   product_name varchar(20)
);

insert into product values (1,'widget'); 
insert into product values (2,'sprocket'); 
insert into product values (3,'gizmo'); 

create table `order` (
   order_id  int,
   widget_id int  
); 

insert into `order` values (1,1); 
insert into `order` values (1,2); 
insert into `order` values (1,3); 
insert into `order` values (1,4);  -- half deleted
insert into `order` values (2,1); 
insert into `order` values (2,2);  
insert into `order` values (3,3); 
insert into `order` values (3,4);  -- half deleted  
insert into `order` values (4,4);  -- half deleted 



select   o.order_id, count(*)
from     `order` as o 
         join product as p  
            on o.widget_id=p.product_id   
group    by o.order_id     


+----------+----------+
| order_id | count(*) |
+----------+----------+
|        1 |        3 |
|        2 |        2 |
|        3 |        1 |
+----------+----------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

```
mysql> select   o.order_id,
    ->          p.product_name,
    ->          (case when p.product_id is null
    ->                then 'half_deleted' else '' end) as half_deleted
    -> from     `order` as o
    ->          left outer join product as p
    ->             on o.widget_id=p.product_id
    -> order    by order_id   ;
+----------+--------------+--------------+
| order_id | product_name | half_deleted |
+----------+--------------+--------------+
|        1 | gizmo        |              |
|        1 | NULL         | half_deleted |
|        1 | widget       |              |
|        1 | sprocket     |              |
|        2 | widget       |              |
|        2 | sprocket     |              |
|        3 | gizmo        |              |
|        3 | NULL         | half_deleted |
|        4 | NULL         | half_deleted |
+----------+--------------+--------------+
```