# Left join sql query gives values which are not present in one of the tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

When I execute the below query on Microsoft SQL Server 2012, I get values which are not present in the table RequiredVisitLink. Why is this happening? I was expecting to get values only common to both and which satisfy the condition.

```
select a.ID from table1 a left join table2 b on a.ID = b.ID where Baseball=1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `inner join` instead of `left join`

```
select a.ID from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.ID = b.ID where Baseball=1
```

The `INNER JOIN` keyword selects all rows from both tables as long as there is a match between the columns in both tables.

The `LEFT JOIN` keyword returns all rows from the left table (table1), with the matching rows in the right table (table2). The result is NULL in the right side when there is no match.

Answer (score -1):

instead left join, **try**

> Left Outer join
>
> Right Outer join
>
> Inner join

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` are just the same. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4401540/4273446