# How to insert NULL value in MySQL column with no match?

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following two tables:

projects_expended:

```
+---------------+------------+----------+
| project_name  | project_id | Utilised |
+---------------+------------+----------+
| CStreamTax    |          1 |     3500 |
| CStreamTravel |          2 |      149 |
+---------------+------------+----------+
```

projects:

```
+------------+---------------------+
| project_id | project_budgetstart |
+------------+---------------------+
|          1 |               15000 |
|          2 |               15000 |
|          3 |                 500 |
+------------+---------------------+
```

I would like to make a joint table of the two, but with the Utilised
field filled with `NULL` when a project_id form the projects table does
not match one of the entries in the projects_expended table.

My basic attempt was as follows:

```
SELECT projects.*, projects_expended.utilised
  FROM projects_expended
  JOIN projects
    ON projects.project_id = projects_expended.project_id;
```

And the result:

```
+------------+---------------------+----------+
| project_id | project_budgetstart | utilised |
+------------+---------------------+----------+
|          1 |               15000 |     3500 |
|          2 |               15000 |      149 |
+------------+---------------------+----------+
```

I understand why I get the result I get. But I'm pretty stuck with this.
I've made other attempts (too many to count).

Comment: search for outer join

Comment: Indeed. Will mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Use left outer join:

```
SELECT projects.*, projects_expended.utilised
  FROM projects
  LEFT OUTER JOIN projects_expended

    ON projects.project_id = projects_expended.project_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. But that gave me the same results as my normal JOIN.

Comment: @PleaseWait Sorry my fault. See my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer from:

[LEFT JOIN vs. LEFT OUTER JOIN in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-and-left-outer-join-in-sql-server)

It was pretty helpful.

The solution:

```
SELECT projects.*, projects_expended.utilised
  FROM projects_expended
 RIGHT JOIN projects
    ON projects.project_id = projects_expended.project_id;
```