# SQL Server replaces LEFT JOIN for LEFT OUTER JOIN in view query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view

I need to use a LEFT JOIN in a View however SQL Server replaces LEFT JOIN for LEFT OUTER JOIN every time I save my view.

When trying to use LEFT INNER JOIN explicitly I get the error "Incorrect syntax near word 'INNER'". What is more when I want to create an index for the view I get the error "Cannot add clustered index to views using OUTER JOINS".

It's maddening, and ideas why this could be happening?

[image]

So when I try to create an index for the view I get the message I used an outer join though I didn't.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT INNER JOIN`?

Comment: yes, and it works. However it's not what I want to do (I need all rows from table A not just the ones that overlap)

Comment: Okay, I guess I don't understand what the problem is then. I just know that the error is complaining about the syntax because you can't use `LEFT INNER JOIN` in SQL server. The list of possible joins can be found at [W3Schools SQL Joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

Comment: I know I have to use a `LEFT JOIN` in SQL Server. But when I save my `LEFT JOIN` SQL Server changes it to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: That's because `LEFT JOIN` is the same as `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in SQL server silly :P. The answer on this [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-and-left-outer-join-in-sql-server) question provides an excellent explanation about it :).

Comment: the problem is that when trying to add an index to the view I get the error I used an outer join. The whole point of the View is to do JOINS so I'm struggling to understand how to add the index. .

Comment: If the view requires an outer join then it cannot be index.  Calling it a left inner join is not going to fix that.

Comment: hi @Blam could you explain me why it cannot be indexed? I've been told the DB is having a poor performance and I thought I would be able to index it to improve it.

Comment: Ask Microsoft.   That message is very clear.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are getting the joins confused and keep in mind there are different ways of writing joins. What you're looking for is a LEFT OUTER JOIN(OUTER is an optional). There is no LEFT INNER JOIN.

There are three major types of joins.

### Type 1: INNER JOIN - only where both tables match

**1.) INNER JOIN** aka **JOIN**

### Type 2: OUTER JOINS where either one or both tables match

**1.) LEFT OUTER JOIN** aka **LEFT JOIN**

**2.) RIGHT OUTER JOIN** aka **RIGHT JOIN**

**3.) FULL OUTER JOIN** aka **FULL JOIN**

### Type 3: CROSS JOIN - Cartesian product(all possible combos of each table)

**1.) Cross Join**

Here's a graphic showing how each works:

[image]

Comment: Your answer saved me; even though I've been a SQL programmer for a few years, for some reason I had this belief that there exists a "LEFT INNER JOIN". No idea why i was thinking that