# Select from multiple tables Mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables :

```
Table A1 : ID|Name|Date|Id_person
Table B1 : ID|Name|Date|Id_person
Table C1 : ID|Name|Date|Id_person
```

I want a query like:

```
select * from table A1 as a , table B1 as b , table C1 as c where a.Id_person=1 or b.Id_person=1 or c.Id_person=1
```

I get result only if id_person=1 in the 3 tables,
And i get no result if just one the 3 table don't respect the condition.

How to get result from the tables even if one of theme don't respect the condition (id_person=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
SELECT * FROM A1 WHERE Id_person=1 UNION SELECT * FROM A2 WHERE Id_person=1 UNION SELECT * FROM A3 WHERE Id_person=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that :

```
select * from table A1 as a 
left join table B1 as b on a.Id_Person = b.Id_Person
left join table C1 as c on a.Id_Person = c.Id_Person
```

See this post : [LEFT JOIN vs. LEFT OUTER JOIN in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-and-left-outer-join-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

You can try UNION:

```
SELECT * FROM A1 as a WHERE a.Id_person=1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM B1 as b WHERE b.Id_person=1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM C1 as c WHERE c.Id_person=1
```