# Understanding Left Join in Sql

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have the following dataset

```
Table A                   Table B

Name     Age              Name      Eye Color
Ashish   24               Ashish    Brown 
Max      16               George    Black
Rehan    12               Tim       White
Tim      16               Sadhana   Blue 
maggie   25               Ashsih    Brown 
martha   27               Ashish    Black
```

Now i need to understand for the record **Ashish** , how many rows will be created in the resulting table.  if i am performing left join between Table A and Table B , where Table A is on the Left Side and B on right.

Comment: Why don't you try it first?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Left join and Left outer join in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-and-left-outer-join-in-sql-server)

Comment: Are you really going to join using names? Aren't there any foreign key

Comment: I just need to understand how does the left join works , I know all the rows from the Left table will be displayed and the matching one from right will be displayed . I just need to have a picture of the resulting table by applying left join because "Ashish"  has duplicate entries.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Answer (score 1):

As the table B has three rows for that value, you will have three rows returned when using a LEFT JOIN

Comment: Can you describe in detail , the resultant rows finally

Comment: @Always_Learning, isn't enough? What kind of details do you expect more?

Comment: Can you please draw the resultant table. That will be enough for me.