# Create a view by joining three tables

Tags: sql, inner-join, outer-join, join

I am attempting to join three tables.  One table has profile information, the second table has admission information and the third has discharge information.

#### Table 1: Member Information

```
No, 
Name, 
Sex, 
DBO, 
CaseNo, 
SeqNum,
StartDate,
......
```

#### Table 2: Auth Information

```
No,
Name,    
DBO,
CaseNo,
SeqNum,
StartDate,
Admin_1,
Admin_2,
Admin_3,
...
```

#### Table 3: Discharge Information

```
CaseNo,
SeqNum,
DisDate,
DisRea,
...
```

#### This is my query:

```
Select    a.no, 
          a.Name, 
          a.Sex, 
          a.DBO, 
          a.CaseNo, 
          a.SeqNum,
          a.StartDate,
          b.Admin_1,
          b.Admin_2,
          b.Admin_3,
          c.DisDate,
          c.DisRea
 from     dbo.mem_information as a inner join dbo.auth_information as b on b.caseno = a.caseno AND 
          b.seqnum = a.seqnum AND        
          b.StartDate = a.StartDate 
          inner join dbo.discharge_information as c ON c.caseno = b.caseno AND
          c.seqnum = b.seqnum
```

#### Sample of my results:

```
 Name   Sex     DBO     CaseNo  SeqNum  Admin_1  Admin_2 Admin_3 DisDate DisRea
  Jones   M    19980615    23      1       SING
  Jones   M    19980615    23      1               LAUGH
  Smith   F    19960212    24      1       SING
```

#### Desired Results:

```
 Name  Sex     DBO     CaseNo  SeqNum  Admin_1  Admin_2 Admin_3 DisDate DisRea
 Jones   M    19980615    23      1     SING     LAUGH            
 Smith   F    19960212    24      1     SING
```

There may not be any discharge data yet but, I would like for the fields to appear as NULL.

Comment: You seem to have quite a bit of redundancy in your tables (e. g. `No, 
Name` and `DBO` are in both `member_info` and `auth_info`) which you should try to reduce. It might cause you a head-ache at some point otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly how to test this since you haven't provided any sample data, but I am assuming you are looking for something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.VIEW_NAME AS
SELECT a.[no]
    ,a.NAME
    ,a.Sex
    ,a.DBO
    ,a.CaseNo
    ,a.SeqNum
    ,MIN(a.StartDate) StartDate
    ,MAX(b.Admin_1) Admin_1
    ,MAX(b.Admin_2) Admin_2
    ,MAX(b.Admin_3) Admin_3
    ,MAX(c.DisDate) DisDate
    ,MAX(c.DisRea) DisRea
FROM dbo.mem_information AS a
INNER JOIN dbo.auth_information AS b ON b.caseno = a.caseno
    AND b.seqnum = a.seqnum
    AND b.StartDate = a.StartDate
LEFT JOIN dbo.discharge_information AS c ON c.caseno = b.caseno
    AND c.seqnum = b.seqnum
GROUP BY  a.[no]
    ,a.NAME
    ,a.Sex
    ,a.DBO
    ,a.CaseNo
    ,a.SeqNum;
```

Comment: This will probably work well, if there is at max. *one* value per casenum/seqnum and for each of the columns `Admin1, Admin2, Admin3, DisRate` and `Disrea`. If there should be more values floating around you would need another approach.

Comment: @cars10 Definitely agree with you there! Yeah I think the OP has not clearly described his requirements. So, I am making a lot of assumptions here.

Comment: Okay I made the changes and everything works except for the left join.  It just loops for hours.

Comment: I finally got back to the query and got it working thanks.  Now my only issue is that the query is slow.  How can I create a view and index on this query to speed it up?

Comment: @tnbumbray The above code should have already created a view for you. As far as the performance goes, maybe you could start by creating an index on `StartDate` column. Usually, date joins are very troublesome.

Answer (score 1):

Beside Null fields there is solution if there is no discharge data then there may be no entries. you should use left join to combine table 'discharge_information'.
sql query like:

```
Select    a.no, 
          a.Name, 
          a.Sex, 
          a.DBO, 
          a.CaseNo, 
          a.SeqNum,
          a.StartDate,
          b.Admin_1,
          b.Admin_2,
          b.Admin_3,
          c.DisDate,
          c.DisRea
 from     dbo.mem_information as a inner join dbo.auth_information as b on b.caseno = a.caseno AND 
          b.seqnum = a.seqnum AND        
          b.StartDate = a.StartDate 
          left join dbo.discharge_information as c ON c.caseno = b.caseno AND
          c.seqnum = b.seqnum;
```

see here usage for joins [LEFT JOIN vs. LEFT OUTER JOIN in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-and-left-outer-join-in-sql-server)