# The opposite of INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have query with `Inner Join`.

**Query 1**:

```
   select *
     from vehicle_models vmodel
     Inner join ogpo_voilure_model md on md.Name = vmodel.VEHICLE_MODEL
```

Now, i Need data that not exists in these id. With another word - opposite `Inner JOIN`.

I tried to make query that I need, but not successfull.

**Query 2**:

```
Select top 500 *
 from ogpo_voilure_model md
 Where md.id not in
 (
 select md.id
     from Novelty.dbo.vehicle_models vmodel
     Inner join [ogpo_voilure_model] md on md.Name = vmodel.VEHICLE_MODEL
 )
```

I find in `StakOverflow` answer like [this(sixth example)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406333/4732301). But my fields are not `NULL`.

How I can achieve it?

Comment: Well the opposite to INNER is...surprise...OUTER. Try it out.

Comment: @flowit: results of outer join would be a superset of those of inner join, not the complement.

Comment: @flowit, You don't understand the question.

Comment: @ШыназАлиш: what exactly are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: @ШыназАлиш provide sample data and desired results than.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, See the sixth image of [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/406333/4732301), but my ids are not null.

Comment: is it possible to prepare a sqlfiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/) for better understanding ?

Comment: @ШыназАлиш: your "query 2" seems like it should work. Why didn't it? If you create a sample dataset on sqlfiddle, we'll take a stab at it.

Comment: Your query is looking fine. Maybe you mean something else?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, My **Query 2** returns me 0 results. But I know that result must be more than **10k**.

Comment: So have you tried the sixth example? You only get NULL fields when for one value there is no adequate join partner. This depends on your data.

Comment: The reason you are getting 0 rows maybe in that your `Query 1` contains records with `md.id` is `NULL`. In this case clause `Where md.id not in (select ...)` always fails.

Answer (score 0):

The inner join means you want everything is in set table **vehicle_models** but also got one or more correlated row in **ogpo_voilure_model**

If you define the oposite to it as everything is in **vehicle_models** but don't got a correlated in **ogpo_voilure_model**

All you needs is:

```
select *
     from [Novelty].[dbo].[vehicle_models] vmodel
     Where vmodel.VEHICLE_MODEL not in
     (
       select md.Name
       from [Novelty].[dbo].[ogpo_voilure_model] md
     )
```

And following that definition it's right even if results returns zero rows.
If it's not the right answer you must first define what the opposite of inner join means to you. For example you maybe want to swap the tables.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "my fields are not `NULL`"?

The [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-and-left-outer-join-in-sql-server/406333#406333) that you gave in the question has an answer: `FULL JOIN`.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    vehicle_models vmodel
    FULL JOIN ogpo_voilure_model md on md.Name = vmodel.VEHICLE_MODEL
WHERE
    md.Name IS NULL
    OR vmodel.VEHICLE_MODEL IS NULL
;
```

This will return rows from `vehicle_models` and `ogpo_voilure_model` that don't have common Vehicle Model Name.

It would help if you could add few sample rows to the question and your expected result.