# How to Write a Left Outer Join with WHERE clause in Pig Latin?

Tags: apache-pig

I have two relations with defined schemas.  I wish to find get only the records from relationA that do not exist in relation (see left middle visualization on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-and-left-outer-join-in-sql-server?rq=1)).

I've tried the two variations below with no success as they both return the error below.  How do I perform this type of operation in Pig?

> "ERROR 1200 mismatched input 'WHERE' expecting SEMI-COLON."

```
join_result = JOIN relationA by (project_id, sequence_id) LEFT OUTER, relationB by (project_id, sequence_id) WHERE relationB (project_id, sequence_id)is null;

join_result = JOIN relationA by (project_id, sequence_id) LEFT OUTER, relationB by (project_id, sequence_id) WHERE (relationB.project_id is null) AND (relationB.sequence_id is null);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "WHERE" clause in [JOIN](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/basic.html#join-outer) in PIG.You will have to use FILTER for eliminating records based on a condition.

```
join_result = JOIN relationA by (project_id, sequence_id) LEFT OUTER, relationB by (project_id, sequence_id);
final_result = FILTER join_result BY (relationB.project_id is null AND relationB.sequence_id is null);
```