# How to join those two tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with the following structure:

```
|=================|
| posts           |
|=================|
| ID | Title      |
|-----------------|
| 1  | Title #1   |
|-----------------|
| 2  | Title #1   |
|-----------------|
| 3  | Title #1   |
|-----------------|
| 4  | Title #1   |
|-----------------|
| 5  | Title #1   |
|-----------------|
```

and

```
|==========================================|
| meta                                     |
|==========================================|
| id | post_id | meta_key   | meta_value   |
|------------------------------------------|
| 1  | 1       | key_one    | value for #1 |
|------------------------------------------|
| 2  | 1       | key_two    | value for #1 |
|------------------------------------------|
| 3  | 1       | key_three  | value for #1 |
|------------------------------------------|
| 4  | 2       | key_one    | value for #2 |
|------------------------------------------|
| 5  | 2       | key_three  | value for #2 |
|------------------------------------------|
| 6  | 3       | key_one    | value for #3 |
|------------------------------------------|
| 7  | 3       | key_three  | value for #3 |
|------------------------------------------|
```

and I need to get the following single result:

```
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
| ID | Post Title | Meta Key One | Meta Key Two | Meta Key Three |
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | Title #1   | value for #1 | value for #1 | value for #1   |
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
| 2  | Title #2   | value for #2 | null         | value for #2   |
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
| 3  | Title #3   | value for #3 | null         | value for #3   |
|----------------------------------------------------------------|
```

But I don't know how to do this.

The SQL Query I have build until now is this:

```
SELECT
   `p`.`ID` AS `ID`,
   `p`.`Title` AS `Post Title`,
   `mt1`.`meta_value` AS `Meta Key One`,
   `mt2`.`meta_value` AS `Meta Key One`,
FROM
    posts AS `p`
    LEFT JOIN `meta` AS `mt1` ON ( `p`.`ID` = `mt1`.`post_id` )
    LEFT JOIN `meta` AS `mt2` ON ( `p`.`ID` = `mt2`.`post_id` )
WHERE
    1 = 1
    AND `mt1`.`meta_key` = 'key_one'
    AND `mt2`.`meta_key` = 'key_three';
```

The problem is that if I add a third `LEFT JOIN` in `meta` table to use it later on in `WHERE` clause and say `mt1.meta_key = 'key_two'` I get only one record instead of three.

Does anyone know how can I achieve this with a single query ?

I don't know if that helps, but I have create an SQL Fiddle here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af591f/1

Note that the column names in fiddle doesn't meet the ones in my example, but the problem remains the same.

Comment: As a general rule: criteria on an outer joined table belongs in the `ON` clause not in the `WHERE` clause. This is where your query fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/af591f/4

```
SELECT 
  `b`.`id` AS `ID`,
  `b`.`title` AS `Title`,
  mt1.meta_value `KeyOne`,
  mt2.meta_value `KeyTwo`,
  mt3.meta_value `KeyThree`
FROM 
  `base` as `b`
  LEFT JOIN `meta` mt1 ON b.id = mt1.base_id AND mt1.meta_key = 'key_one' 
  LEFT JOIN `meta` mt2 ON b.id = mt2.base_id AND mt2.meta_key = 'key_two' 
  LEFT JOIN `meta` mt3 ON b.id = mt3.base_id AND mt3.meta_key = 'key_three'
```

Comment: You should use OUTER join for this, because otherwise you wont get the second and third desired output row.

Comment: you can check : http://stackoverflow.com/a/406333/4421474 there is no difference between `LEFT JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Answer (score 4):

You can use *conditional aggregation* for this:

```
SELECT p.ID, p.Title AS 'Post Title',
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'key_one' THEN meta_value END) AS 'Meta Key One',
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'key_two' THEN meta_value END) AS 'Meta Key Two',
       MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = 'key_three' THEN meta_value END) AS 'Meta Key Three'
FROM posts AS p
LEFT JOIN meta AS m ON p.ID = m.post_id
GROUP BY p.ID, p.Title
```

The benefit of this method is that you use `LEFT JOIN` just once, so it is easily extensible in order to accommodate additional key values.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/631f2/1)

Answer (score 1):

You join tables by column, you don't join columns by columns.. Since you only have two tables you only need one join. Start with this query and change the `*` to whatever columns you need.

```
select 
    * --or whatever
from
posts p
left join meta m on p.id = m.post_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
   `p`.`ID` AS `ID`,
   `p`.`Title` AS `Post Title`,
   `mt1`.`meta_value` AS `Meta Key One`,
   `mt2`.`meta_value` AS `Meta Key Two`,
   `mt3`.`meta_value` AS `Meta Key Three`
FROM
    posts AS `p`
    LEFT JOIN `meta` AS `mt1` 
        ON ( `p`.`ID` = `mt1`.`post_id` AND `mt1`.`meta_key` = 'key_one')
    LEFT JOIN `meta` AS `mt2` 
        ON ( `p`.`ID` = `mt2`.`post_id` AND `mt2`.`meta_key` = 'key_two')
    LEFT JOIN `meta` AS `mt3` 
        ON ( `p`.`ID` = `mt3`.`post_id` AND `mt3`.`meta_key` = 'key_three')
```