# Which join i want to use to get rows from left table that not found in right table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables has below

Table Left:

```
ID   | Visit No 
---  | --------
 1   |   1
 1   |   2
 2   |   1
 3   |   1
```

If Table Right has

```
ID  | Visit No | Place
--- | -------- | -----
 1  |  1       | Chennai
```

Then Results will be like

```
 ID  | Visit No 
---  | --------     
 1   |   2
 2   |   1
 3   |   1
```

If Table Right is Empty, Then the Result will be

```
ID   | Visit No 
---  | --------
 1   |   1
 1   |   2
 2   |   1
 3   |   1
```

Based on ID and Visit No. Is it possible to get output using joins in SQL Sever 2012.

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-and-left-outer-join-in-sql-server#406333 especially the graphics part, they're very useful for understanding the types of joins

Comment: sure. I will go through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT left.[ID], left.[Visit No]
FROM LeftTable left
LEFT JOIN RightTable right
  ON left.[ID] = right.[ID]
  AND left.[Visit No] = right.[Visit No]
WHERE right.[ID] IS NULL
```