# Combine result set in FULL OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

```
|ORDER_ID|ORDER_DATE|AMOUNT|
|00000001| 12-SEP-16|   900|
|00000002| 13-SEP-16|  1400|
|00000003| 14-SEP-16|  1000|
|00000004| 15-SEP-16|   700|

|ORDER_ID|PURCHASE_ID|PURCHASE_DATE|AMOUNT|
|00000002|   00000001|    20-SEP-16|  1450|
|00000004|   00000002|    21-SEP-16|   750|
```

I want the result to be like this:

```
|ORDER_ID|DATE     |AMOUNT_ORDER|AMOUNT_PURCHASE|
|00000001|12-SEP-16|         900|               |
|00000002|20-SEP-16|        1400|           1450|
|00000003|14-SEP-16|        1000|               |
|00000004|21-SEP-16|         700|            750|
```

So far I do this query:

```
SELECT 
  a.ORDER_ID,
  CASE WHEN b.ORDER_ID IS NULL
  THEN a.ORDER_DATE
  ELSE b.PURCHASE_DATE
  END AS DATE,
  a.AMOUNT AS AMOUNT_ORDER
  b.AMOUNT AS AMOUNT_PURCHASE
FROM TABLE_A a
FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE_B b
ON a.ORDER_ID = b.ORDER_ID
```

Is there another efficient way to query this?

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: You don't need to use Full Outer Join, you can use a simple join from table b to table a because order id in table b doesn't allow null values (That's my assumption)

Answer (score 0):

According to your requirement you can achieve same output using LEFT JOIN instead: If data must available in both tables then INNER JOIN is the best way and this is the reference where you can get overview of all the joins [LEFT JOIN vs. LEFT OUTER JOIN in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-vs-left-outer-join-in-sql-server) hope it will be helpful.

```
SELECT 
  a.ORDER_ID,
  CASE WHEN b.ORDER_ID IS NULL THEN a.ORDER_DATE
  ELSE 
  b.PURCHASE_DATE
  END AS DATE,
  a.AMOUNT AS AMOUNT_ORDER
  b.AMOUNT AS AMOUNT_PURCHASE
FROM TABLE_A a
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B b ON a.ORDER_ID = b.ORDER_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want Full result set from both  table then use full outer join.

```
                select 
                a.ORDER_ID,
                coalesce (a.order_date,b.purchase_date) as DATE,
                a.AMOUNT AS AMOUNT_ORDER,
                b.AMOUNT AS AMOUNT_PURCHASE
                from #table_a a
                full outer join #table_b b on b.ORDER_ID=a.ORDER_ID 
                order by  a.ORDER_ID
```

if you want only result from Table_a use Left join.

```
            select 
            a.ORDER_ID,
            coalesce (a.order_date,b.purchase_date) as DATE,
            a.AMOUNT AS AMOUNT_ORDER,
            b.AMOUNT AS AMOUNT_PURCHASE
            from #table_a a
            left join #table_b b on b.ORDER_ID=a.ORDER_ID 
            order by  a.ORDER_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.ORDER_ID
    ,CASE 
        WHEN b.ORDER_ID IS NULL
            THEN a.ORDER_DATE
        ELSE b.PURCHASE_DATE
        END AS DATE
    ,a.AMOUNT AS AMOUNT_ORDER b.AMOUNT AS AMOUNT_PURCHASE
FROM TABLE_A a
RIGHT JOIN TABLE_B b ON a.ORDER_ID = b.ORDER_ID
```