# how to write SQl Query to LINQ to SQL MVC entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

This is my sql Query:
`SELECT ParkingPlaceName, NoOfParkingPlaces, COUNT(Place.ParkingAreaID) AS NoOfCarsParked, NoOfParkingPlaces-COUNT(Place.ParkingAreaID)
 FROM ParkingArea
LEFT JOIN Place ON ParkingArea.ParkingAreaID = Place.ParkingAreaID
LEFT JOIN Car ON Car.CarID = Place.CarID
GROUP BY ParkingPlaceName, NoOfParkingPlaces, Place.ParkingAreaID`
how to write in LINQ to SQL Query

Comment: the left join to `Car` is needed?

Comment: actually i am using LEFT OUTER JOIN

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` are the same https://stackoverflow.com/q/406294/125981

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `DefaultIfEmpty` method to perform left outer join between 3 tables with `let` statements to deal with group results, hence the LINQ version from your SQL query should be similar (or same) like below:

```
var query = from pa in ParkingArea
            from pl in Place.Where(x => pa.ParkingAreaID == x.ParkingAreaID).DefaultIfEmpty()
            from ca in Car.Where(x => x.CarID == pl.CarID).DefaultIfEmpty()
            group new { pa, pl.ParkingAreaID, ca.CarID } by new { pa.ParkingPlaceName, pa.NoOfParkingPlaces, pl.ParkingAreaID } into grp
            let ParkingPlaceName = grp.Select(x => x.ParkingPlaceName)
            let NoOfParkingPlaces = grp.Select(x => x.NoOfParkingPlaces)
            let NoOfCarsParked = grp.Select(x => x.ParkingAreaID).Count()
            select new
            {
                ParkingPlaceName,
                NoOfParkingPlaces,
                NoOfCarsParked,
                AvailableParkingPlaces = NoOfParkingPlaces - NoOfCarsParked // new alias for holding substraction
            };
```

I decided not to use `join ... in ... on ... equals ...` directly after first and third `from` clauses, since it may lead into confusion about which table instance should be handled when creating group elements after performing `join`.