# How to Connect two tables in derby SQL

Tags: sql, derby

I am working on a project for getting my degree from university, as i am fresh graduated student of Computer Science, and i have a problem that how to connect two tables in SQL Netbeans java Derby database connection.

Thanks;

Comment: This is a very basic SQL question. I suggest you read a book or use a tutorial to learn SQL. You will very quickly get to the chapter where more than one table is involved.

Answer (score 1):

Guessing you means joins- look at this it explains the different types well:

[LEFT JOIN vs. LEFT OUTER JOIN in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-vs-left-outer-join-in-sql-server)