# SQL - Need to conditionally join based on value in TableB column

Tags: sql

I need to know the rows in `TABLE A` that have join records in `TABLE B` based a column value in `TABLE B`, but I also need to return rows in which a row in `TABLE A` has no match in `TABLE B`.

It seems like I need a LEFT JOIN and a LEFT OUTER JOIN, so I'm not sure what to do there. I understand how to do each, but don't understand how to do them together.

The schema looks like:

```
TABLE_A
pk

TABLE_B
pk
a_fk
some_value
```

I need the joined rows where Table_A has no join record in Table_B OR Table_A has a join record row in Table_B (it can have many) in which some_value does not equal "thisValue"

Thanks.

Comment: check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-vs-left-outer-join-in-sql-server

Comment: If add sample data and desired result, will be easy to understand your requirement

Comment: I have added details. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A Left join is a left outer join. Outer joins preserve one of the tables which is what you are after so good guess.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table A
LEFT JOIN Table B
ON TableA.Column = TableB.Column
AND B.SomeValue <> 'ThisValue'
```

All of the rows with a match will have the B information populated all of those without will have nulls in the B data

Comment: @mstrom I have added an extra join conditional that should fit your requirements