# Joining one table all columns and second table few columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables:- `PERSON` and `DATA`. What I want to do is fetch all details from `PERSON` table and only two columns from `DATA` table only when `PERSON.personId = DATA.personId`.

I am using this query:-

```
SELECT *
FROM PERSON AND SELECT DATA.value, DATA.field
FROM DATA where PERSON.personId = DATA.personId;
```

But I think this is wrong syntax. Can anyone tell me what is the right syntax for it.

Comment: I think you need to have a look at the MySQL [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html). Look for the syntax of `JOIN`. There are a lot examples there as well.

Comment: Sit down with any introductory book or tutorial, then get back to us with any questions you may have.

Comment: If this question is solved then please consider accepting an answer (not necessarily mine). Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT p.*,d.column1,d.column2
  FROM Person p 
  JOIN Data d
       ON p.personId = d.personId
WHERE <Condition>
```

In this query person with all columns and data with your desire column you can fetch by this query.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
  select
        P.*,
        D.value,
        D.field
    from Person P
    join Data D on P.PersonID = D.PersonID
```

change P.* to the specific columns that you need but P.* will get everything from the Person table.

check this post out [LEFT JOIN vs. LEFT OUTER JOIN in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-vs-left-outer-join-in-sql-server) to learn about `JOINS`, the diagram is good to understand what the different ones do

Answer (score 1):

Its really easy, Just execute this query:

```
SELECT 
    PERSON.*,
    DATA.value,
    DATA.field
FROM 
    PERSON INNER JOIN DATA USING (`personId`);
```

It selects all fields of PERSON + value and field from DATA.
Also it uses personId to join the two tables.

Fill free to ask if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the correct syntax for achieving what you've asked for:

```
SELECT PERSON.column1,PERSON.column2,PERSON.columnN,DATA.value
FROM PERSON
INNER JOIN DATA 
ON PERSON.personId = DATA.personId
```

- Line#1: lists the columns that you want to select with references to their parent tables.
- Line#2 and 3: are the two tables that you want to select from and join with
- Line#4: is the join condition between the two tables (with matching IDs or other information)

Answer (score 0):

You can use join (LEFT JOIN)

```
SELECT * FROM PERSON LEFT JOIN DATA ON PERSON.personId = DATA.personId
```

Hope it will help you