# SQL add attribute from another table

Tags: sql

```
Table WORK
(WORK ID, TITLE, DESCRIPTION, ARTIST ID)

Table ARTIST
(ARTIST ID, FIRSTNAME, LAST NAME, DATE OF BIRTH, DATE OF DEATH)
```

Hi
My problem is that I have to display the details of all works of art (including the name of the artist who created the work) that are signed.
I managed to go until

```
Select * from Work WHERE DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Signed%'
```

and it displays

```
WorkID  TITLE   DESCRIPTION   ARTISTID

123     1455    Signed        12
```

However, I must display

```
WorkID  TITLE   DESCRIPTION   ARTISTID   FIRSTNAME  LASTNAME

123     1455    Signed        12
```

How do I do that? I know it has something to do with JOIN but I'm not very sure.

Comment: I don't get how you are getting your results, you are selecting * from a table where description is like 'Signed' but the description column shows a value of '1123'

Comment: Hi i censored the problem by adding fake values and did not take that into account. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Inner Join will do or can try left join if u need to

```
SELECT W.*, A.FirstNAme, A.LastName from work w inner join Artist A on 
        A.Artistid 
     = W.ArtistId where A.Description LIKE '%Signed%'
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, it works!
However being new to SQL could you explain the shortcuts you used. Like how does W.* works and what is 'work w' or 'Artist A'?

Answer (score 0):

Use inner join to get the records that exist in both tables

```
Select W.WorkID, W.TITLE, W.DESCRIPTION, W.ARTISTID, A.FIRSTNAME, A.LASTNAME
From Work W
Inner Join Artist A on W.WorkID = A.WorkID
Where Description LIKE '%Signed%'
```

a left outer join would get all the records in the work table and the matching ones in the artist table.

Check this post out to understand joins a bit more : [JOINS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-vs-left-outer-join-in-sql-server)