# join or merge two table based on id merge

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

[image]

I am looking for the results like mentioned in the last.

I tried `union` (only similar col can be merged), `left join`, `right join` i am getting repeated fields in Null areas what can be other options where i can get null without column repeating

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 0):

A full join would get all results from both tables.

```
select
A.ID,
A.ColA,
A.ColB,
B.ColC,
B.ColD
from TableA A
full join Table B on A.ID = B.ID
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-vs-left-outer-join-in-sql-server) is a good post to understand joins

Answer (score 0):

You can try `distinct`:

```
select distinct * from 
tableA a, 
tableB b 
where a.id = b.id;
```

It will not give any duplicate tuples.