# Get records from a table that hit all detail types in another table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have two tables, `Table1` contains master records and `Table2` contains details. 
How I can get all records in `Table1` that hit all details in `Table2`

```
CREATE Table1 ([ID] INT , [Title] VARCHAR(256))
CREATE Table2 ([ID] INT, [Table1_ID] INT, [Detail] INT)
```

Sample:

```
Table1:
ID   Title
---------------
1    Data_1
2    Data_2
3    Data_3


Table2
ID   Table1_ID       Detail
-------------------------------
1        1             500
2        1             600
3        2             500
4        3             500
5        3             600
```

I need to this result:

```
Result:
Table1_ID    Table1_Title
----------------------
1              Data_1
3              Data_3
```

I'm looking for a way with best performance.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text.)

Comment: Please check my answer and mark it as a solution if it worked for you.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190014(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @jarlh Sample data was added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution I am not sure if it is the best way to do this?

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE ([ID] INT, [Title] VARCHAR(256));
DECLARE @T2 TABLE ([ID] INT, [Table1_ID] INT, [Detail] INT);

INSERT  INTO @T1
VALUES
                (1, 'Data_1'),
                (2, 'Data_2'),
                (3, 'Data_3');

INSERT  INTO @T2
VALUES
                (1, 1, 500),
                (2, 1, 600),
                (3, 2, 500),
                (4, 3, 500),
                (5, 3, 600);


DECLARE @DetailCount INT
SELECT @DetailCount = COUNT(DISTINCT [Detail]) FROM @T2

SELECT
        T1.[ID] [Table1_ID],
        T1.[Title] [Table1_Title]
FROM
        @T1 T1 INNER JOIN 
        @T2 T2 ON T1.[ID] = T2.[Table1_ID]
GROUP BY
        T1.[ID],
        T1.[Title]
HAVING
        COUNT(T2.[Detail]) = @DetailCount
```

Comment: What if you have `(4, 'Data_4')` too? and I think you say in your Q _ How I can get all records in Table1 that hit all details in Table2_, No?

Comment: 500 and 600 is my details and  (4, 'Data_4') not hit any details in my sample!

Answer (score 1):

This is basic inner join example:

```
select Table1.ID, Title 
from Table1
inner join Table2 on Table1.ID = Table2.Table1_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

An `INNER JOIN` between the two tables will get you the results that exist in both tables, so :

```
SELECT
    T1.ID, T1.Title
FROM Table1 T1
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.Table1_ID
```

Would get you all the records from the tables were the ID from Table1 is in Table2

There's a splendid post [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-vs-left-outer-join-in-sql-server) which explains the different types of joins

Comment: That's the one @Sami

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE (ID INT, Title VARCHAR(256));
DECLARE @T2 TABLE (ID INT, Table1_ID INT, Detail INT);

INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES
(1,'Data_1'),
(2,'Data_2'),
(3,'Data_3');

INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES
(1,1,500),
(2,1,600),
(3,2,500),
(4,3,500),
(6,3,600);

SELECT T1.ID Table1_ID, T1.Title Table1_Title
FROM @T1 T1 INNER JOIN @T2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
WHERE T1.ID IN (1,3);
```

Output:

```
+-----------+--------------+
| Table1_ID | Table1_Title |
+-----------+--------------+
|         1 | Data_1       |
|         3 | Data_3       |
+-----------+--------------+
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/LNPNQ38747).

Comment: @Fred So correct it please, and also there is something wrong in your question

Comment: changes are applied

Comment: Now, the only way I can see is to use `IN`