# I need to query two tables in sql/php for a photo gallery database

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, photo_albums and images.

photo_albums

- photo_albums_id: int(11)
- cover_photo_id: int(11)

images

- images_id: int(11)
- img_name: varchar(255)
- photo_albums_id: int(11)

I need to query the database to return all the photo albums, only once, plus the img_name of the cover_photo_id associated with each album. I don't want to return all the photos in each album. It also needs to work if there is no cover image associated with the album. This returns all the photo albums:

```
SELECT * FROM photo_albums ORDER BY photo_albums_id;
```

But I'm not sure how to get the following bit to work:

```
SELECT * FROM images WHERE image_id = cover_photo_id;
```

Comment: You need to read a SQL tutorial. Joins are basic SQL techniques.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple `JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.*, i.img_name
FROM photo_albums AS a
JOIN images AS i ON i.image_id = a.cover_photo_id
```

Comment: Does this count as an SQL tutorial then?

Comment: @Strawberry It counts as a pity answer. I give them out once or twice a week. :)

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the pity answer. I don't do this for a living so excuse me for trying to learn a new skill. However, it doesn't solve the issue of returning all the albums. It only returns albums that have a cover_photo_id.

Comment: You don't learn a skill by getting others to do it for you. Read tutorials and start writing code.

Comment: Jason - I suspect that only a minority of contributors to under this tag do mysql for a living (I don't); but I may be mistaken

Answer (score 0):

You just need `JOIN` the two tables together. `JOIN` is one of the basic and most important things you can learn in `SQL`. There are 3 main types; `INNER`,`OUTER` and `FULL`. There's a cracking post [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406333/8086878) which explains the different types and the diagrams make it really easy to understand.

Once they are `JOIN` you can add your `WHERE` and `ORDER` too it, an example would be:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
WHERE t1.column2 = t2.column3
ORDER BY
    t2.column4
```

This uses an `INNER JOIN` so will only get the records that exist in both table.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, you all pointed me in the right direction. Barmar for the main bit and dbajtr for the link about join types. This did the trick:

```
SELECT a.*, i.img_name
FROM photo_albums 
AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN images AS i ON i.images_id = a.cover_photo_id
WHERE a.status = '1'
```