# SQL: How to join a line from antother table to multiple lines in my table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table A which looks like this:

```
|name|ID|
---------
|cow | 1|
|dog | 1|
|cat | 2|
|bird| 2|
|pig | 2|
```

And I have a table B:

```
|action|ID|
-----------
|eat   | 1|
|drink | 2|
|go    | 3|
```

And I want my result-table to look like this:

```
|name|ID|action|
----------------
|cow | 1|eat   |
|dog | 1|eat   |
|cat | 2|drink |
|bird| 2|drink |
|pig | 2|drink |
```

I tried something like:

```
SELECT * FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID=B.ID
```

But that resulted in many more lines than table A had.
Every other join seems to be wrong too.

What is the way to do it?

Comment: Change `left join` to `join`

Comment: visually -)) https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: visually (so version) ;) - https://stackoverflow.com/a/406333/3840840

Answer (score 1):

You want an inner join, left join includes all rows from table A and only matching details from B, inner join ensures its mutually exclusive so

```
SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.ID=B.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

An `INNER JOIN` on between two tables get only gets the results the exists in both tables, a `LEFT JOIN` will get the results that exist in the left (the table in the `from` statement) and the ones that match in the joined table. If you want to learn the differences, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406294/left-join-vs-left-outer-join-in-sql-server) is a good post about them.

This query will work for you:

```
SELECT
    a.name,
    a.id,
    b.action
FROM A a
INNER JOIN B b ON a.id = b.id;
```

Answer (score -1):

I Think this will work for you

> `SELECT name ,ID, (select action from B where  ID=ID)as (action) FROM A`

Answer (score -1):

you can try

```
SELECT *  FROM A, B
where A.ID = B.ID
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM B
LEFT JOIN A ON B.ID=A.ID
```

Comment: Old style joins are nasty and out dated, don't use those